# How can I get clickable hyperlinks in AlertDialog from a string resource?

Tags: android, user-interface, hyperlink, custom-controls

What I am trying to accomplish is to have clickable hyperlinks in the message text displayed by an `AlertDialog`. While the `AlertDialog` implementation happily underlines and colors any hyperlinks (defined using `<a href="...">` in the string resource passed to `Builder.setMessage`) supplied the links do not become clickable.

The code I am currently using looks like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(
        R.string.Title_About).setMessage(
        getResources().getText(R.string.about))
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon).show();
```

I'd like to avoid using a `WebView` to just display a text snippet.

Comment: Hi! Do you really accomplish declared results ("happily underlines and colors any hyperlinks")? What string value are you passing?

Comment: Yes, the key is to have the message to be displayed in a string resource, which Resources.getText(...) returns as a android.text.Spanned preserving the HTML formatting. As soon as you convert it to a String, though, the magic vanishes.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you are only showing some text and URL[s] in your dialog perhaps the solution is simpler

```
public static class MyOtherAlertDialog {

 public static AlertDialog create(Context context) {
  final TextView message = new TextView(context);
  // i.e.: R.string.dialog_message =>
            // "Test this dialog following the link to dtmilano.blogspot.com"
  final SpannableString s = 
               new SpannableString(context.getText(R.string.dialog_message));
  Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
  message.setText(s);
  message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

  return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
   .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
   .setCancelable(true)
   .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
   .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_action_dismiss, null)
   .setView(message)
   .create();
 }
}
```

As shown here
http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/up29wTQeK_zuz-LLvre9wQ?feat=directlink

[image: Alert dialog with clickable links]

Comment: you probably want to create a layout file and inflate it and use it as the view.

Comment: How would you set the style of the textView to match the one used by default?

Comment: Then, I'm getting error `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

Answer (score 216):

I didn't really like the currently most popular answer because it significantly changes the formatting of the message in the dialog.

Here's a solution that will linkify your dialog text without otherwise changing the text styling:

```
    // Linkify the message
    final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(msg); // msg should have url to enable clicking
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);

    final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setMessage( s )
        .create();

    d.show();

    // Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()
    ((TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: This is the solution that I chose, thanks. One problem however is that it doesn't work for normal html links of the form <a href="http://www.superliminal.com/melinda/greenres.htm">resume</a>. Maybe the one-arg Linkify.addLinks doesn't know how to do that yet? Does anyone know the regex pattern needed to make that work with the fancier versions of addLinks? It's odd because it works fine with my similar mailto link.

Comment: Cheers, Worked for me from within `onCreateDialog` of a `DialogFragment`. Just had to set clickable code at `onStart` given that `show` had been called to invoke the DialogFragment

Comment: This seems to make the entire TextView clickable as opposed to just the links... Any way around this?

Comment: I agree this is a far better option since the original answer is messing up the dialog visually.

Comment: Hey this works fine for me, but are we able to change the text link color to something different, and remove the underline?

Comment: Never mind, found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542210/change-color-of-hyperlink-in-alertdialog

Comment: Excellent answer. I had to throw in a `((TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setClickable(true);` before it worked.

Comment: WOW man, I was suffered from this styling issue for a long time. You saved my app. Thank you.

Comment: View returned by findViewById should be checked with "instanceof TextView", because there is no guarantee that implementation will not change.

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, if using `setMessage(R.string.something)`, it is not necessary to explicitly linkify. It's also not necessary to `create()` the AlertDialog object prior to calling `show()` (it can be called on the Builder), and since `show()` returns the dialog object, the `findViewById(android.R.id.message)` can be chained. Wrap it all in a try-catch just in case the message view is not a TextView, and you have a concise formulation.

Comment: this looses any formated text when using this approach

Comment: Hello, When click on the Hyper link, it doesn't open in the browser.Just display "Open with" but not showing any other option.Is there any way to open link directly in browser.? Thanks.

Comment: @emmby Is there any chance to change the color of the link?

Answer (score 55):

This should make `<a href>` tags to get highlighted as well. Please note that i have just added a few lines to emmby's code. so credit to him

```
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
 .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
 .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Check this link out</a>"))
 .create();
d.show();
// Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()   
    ((TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: If you use html in strings.xml, you don't need to use Html.fromHtml. `setMessage(R.string.cool_link)` works with `<string name="cool_link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Check this link out</a></string>`

Comment: That is true. When you combine both methods (Html.fromHtml and HTML tag in strings.xml) it does notwork.

Comment: Its been a while and fromHtml is deprecated, now what?

Comment: You can still use fromHtml: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String, int)

Simply use ```Html.fromHtml("string with links", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)```

Comment: `setMovementMethod()` is the important part here, otherwise the URL will not be clickable.

Comment: I get a null pointer exception at the last line saying that `((TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message))` is null.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, if you want to simply use a string without dealing with all the views, the fastest way is to find message textview and linkify it:

```
d.setMessage("Insert your cool string with links and stuff here");
Linkify.addLinks((TextView) d.findViewById(android.R.id.message), Linkify.ALL);
```

Answer (score 12):

JFTR, here comes the solution which I figured out after some time:

```
View view = View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.about, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(R.string.Text_About);
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(
        R.string.Title_About).setView(view)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon).show();
```

The corresponding about.xml borrowed as a fragment from the Android sources looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="12dip" android:paddingLeft="14dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/message" style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" android:linksClickable="true" />
</ScrollView>
```

The important parts are setting linksClickable to true and setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()).

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem for me. In my case, it wasn't necessary to `setLinksClickable(true)` (I guess it already was), but `setMovementMethod(...)` made all the difference.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of ...

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.my_title);
dialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.my_text);
```

... I now use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.my_title);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(R.string.my_text);
dialogBuilder.setView(textView);
```

Comment: Hey, your soln works. do you know why the whole textview flashes when clicking on the link though?

Comment: It does not scroll like the default one does.

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way:

```java
final AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.title)
                .setMessage(R.string.message)
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.close_button, null)
                .create();
        dlg.show();
        // Important! android.R.id.message will be available ONLY AFTER show()
        ((TextView)dlg.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 6):

All the above answer will not remove html tag like , etc if the given string contains, I tried to remove all the tags, and this is work fine for me

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setTitle("Title");

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Hello World</b> This is a test of the URL <a href=http://www.example.com> Example</a><p><b>This text is bold</b></p><p><em>This text is emphasized</em></p><p><code>This is computer output</code></p><p>This is<sub> subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup></p>";));
        builder.setView(layout);
AlertDialog alert = builder.show();
```

and the custom_dialog would be like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="10dp"
              >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

The above code will remove all the html tag and shows Example as Click able URL all others in the specified html formatting text.

Answer (score 5):

I was not really satisfied with the current answers. There are two things that are important when you want clickable hyperlinks in href style withing an AlertDialog:

1. Set the content as View and not with `setMessage(…)`, as only Views allow clickable HTML content
2. Set the correct movement method (`setMovementMethod(…)`)

Here is a working minimal example:

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="dialogContent">
    Cool Links:\n
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>\n
    <a href="http://android.stackexchange.com">Android Enthusiasts</a>\n
</string>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
…
public void showCoolLinks(View view) {
   final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
   textView.setText(R.string.dialogContent);
   textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); // this is important to make the links clickable
   final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
       .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
       .setView(textView)
       .create();
   alertDialog.show()
}
…
```

Comment: This works perfectly but the text in the Alert is starting from the very left, without any blank space. You can easily adjust that with `textView.setPadding()`

Answer (score 5):

For me the best solution to create privacy policy dialog is :

```
    private void showPrivacyDialog() {
    if (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(PRIVACY_DIALOG_SHOWN, false)) {

        String privacy_pol = "<a href='https://sites.google.com/view/aiqprivacypolicy/home'> Privacy Policy </a>";
        String toc = "<a href='https://sites.google.com/view/aiqprivacypolicy/home'> T&C </a>";
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("By using this application, you agree to " + privacy_pol + " and " + toc + " of this application."))
                .setPositiveButton("ACCEPT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putBoolean(PRIVACY_DIALOG_SHOWN, true).apply();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("DECLINE", null)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();

        dialog.show();
        TextView textView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setLinksClickable(true);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

check the working example : [app link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidcodeshop.aiq)

Answer (score 3):

I've checked many questions and answers, but it doesn't work. I did it myself. This is the code snippet on MainActivity.java.

```
private void skipToSplashActivity()
{

    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    final SpannableString str = new SpannableString(this.getText(R.string.dialog_message));

    textView.setText(str);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    ....
}
```

Put this tag on res\values\String.xml

```
<string name="dialog_message"><a href="http://www.nhk.or.jp/privacy/english/">NHK Policy on Protection of Personal Information</a></string>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a `DialogFragment`, this solution should help.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // dialog_text contains "This is a http://test.org/"
        String msg = getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_text);
        SpannableString spanMsg = new SpannableString(msg);
        Linkify.addLinks(spanMsg, Linkify.ALL);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
            .setMessage(spanMsg)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Make the dialog's TextView clickable
        ((TextView)this.getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.message))
                .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set the SpannableString as the dialog's message, the link is highlighted, but not clickable.

Comment: @bk138 The call to .setMovementMethod() in onStart() is what makes the link clickable.

Answer (score 2):

I combined some of the options discussed above to come up with this function that works for me.  pass the result to dialog builder's SetView() method.

```
public ScrollView LinkifyText(String message) 
{
    ScrollView svMessage = new ScrollView(this); 
    TextView tvMessage = new TextView(this);

    SpannableString spanText = new SpannableString(message);

    Linkify.addLinks(spanText, Linkify.ALL);
    tvMessage.setText(spanText);
    tvMessage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    svMessage.setPadding(14, 2, 10, 12);
    svMessage.addView(tvMessage);

    return svMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Easy Kotlin implementation

**String resource:**

```
<string name="foo"><a href="https://www.google.com/">some link</a></string>
```

**Code:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setMessage(R.string.foo)
        .show()
        .apply {
            findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.message)
            ?.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        }
```

Comment: this solution is great, but doesn't work from Android 13 anymore I think.

Answer (score 1):

I do this by specifying the alert box in an XML resource and loading that. See for example the [about.xml](http://svn.osafoundation.org/sandbox/heikki/android/ChandlerQE/res/layout/about.xml) (see the ABOUT_URL id) that gets instantiated near the end of [ChandlerQE.java](http://svn.osafoundation.org/sandbox/heikki/android/ChandlerQE/src/org/chandlerproject/android/chandlerqe/ChandlerQE.java). The relevant parts from the java code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = 
    (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, null);

new AlertDialog.Builder(ChandlerQE.this)
.setTitle(R.string.about)
.setView(view)
```

Comment: link is dead, can you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. It creates a normal link without html tags involved and without any URL visible. It also keeps the design intact.

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("This is my link.");
s.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com"), 11, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
} else {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
}

final AlertDialog d = builder
        .setPositiveButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing, just close
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("SHARE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Share the app
                share("Subject", "Text");
            }
        })
        .setIcon(R.drawable.photo_profile)
        .setMessage(s)
        .setTitle(R.string.about_title)
        .create();

d.show();

((TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks, Just to add 
setSpan(URL, startPoint, endPoint, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE). 
Here startPoint and endPoint are words which will be highlighted for clicking

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and shortest way is like this

[Android link in dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095335/android-link-in-dialog)

```
((TextView) new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Info")
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<p>Sample text, <a href=\"http://google.nl\">hyperlink</a>.</p>"))
.show()
// Need to be called after show(), in order to generate hyperlinks
.findViewById(android.R.id.message))
.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way I use

**Strings In strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <string name="credits_title">Credits</string>
    <string name="confirm">OK</string>
    <string name="credits">All rights reserved.
         <a href="https://google.com">Source</a>
    </string>
</resources>
```

**Dimensions In dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="margin_8dp">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_32dp">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**Helper Dialog class**

```
public class MessageHelper {

    public static void showCreditsDialog(Context context) {

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.credits_title);
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        int padding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_32dp);
        int topPadding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_8dp);
        textView.setPadding(padding, topPadding, padding, 0);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setText(R.string.credits);
        alertDialog.setView(textView);

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, context.getResources().getString(R.string.confirm),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
MessageHelper.showCreditsDialog(this); // this is the context
```

Preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Clickable hyperlinks in AlertDialog

```
 /*Dialog Agreement*/
    private fun agreed() {
        if (agreed != "yes") {
            val inflater: LayoutInflater = this.layoutInflater
            val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_agreed, null)
            val btnAccept: TextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_accept)
            val btnDecline: TextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_decline)
            val txtMessage: TextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message)
            btnAccept.setOnClickListener {
                //Saving data to preference manager
                val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Janta24", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                val editor = sharedPref.edit()
                editor.putString("agreed", "yes")
                editor.apply()
                alertDialog.dismiss()
            }
            btnDecline.setOnClickListener {
                finish()
            }
            txtMessage.text = Html.fromHtml(
                "We have revised our<a href=\"http://app.janta24.in/term.html\">Terms of Use</a> & " +
                        "<a href=\"http://app.janta24.in/privacy.html\">Privacy Policy</a> " +
                        "By accepting, you agreed to our updated terms and policies. Please take few minutes to read and understand them."
            )
            txtMessage.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
            val dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            dialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener { }
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)
            dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create()
            alertDialog.show()
        }
    }
```