# How to make links in a TextView clickable

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, clickable

I have the following TextView defined:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/txtCredits"
    android:autoLink="web" android:id="@+id/infoTxtCredits"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

where `@string/txtCredits` is a string resource that contains `<a href="some site">Link text</a>`.

Android is highlighting the links in the TextView, but they do not respond to clicks. What am I doing wrong?  Do I have to set an onClickListener for the TextView in my activity for something as simple as this?

It looks like it has to do with the way I define my string resource.

This does not work:

```
<string name="txtCredits"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></string>
```

But this does:

```
<string name="txtCredits">www.google.com</string>
```

Which is a bummer because I would much rather show a text link than show the full URL.

Comment: android:autoLink="web" this is the main line needs to be added to xml and it works like charm. thanks @Richard

Comment: <string name="txtCredits"><a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a></string> use the above sttring and it works. It is learnt that the string in href and with in anchor tag must be same and have .com or .* to work need to check why

Comment: <string name="txtCredits">Some text here<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></string>

For above snippet Click on Some text here should not work in my case what should i do ?

Comment: try https://github.com/ajaysahani/MultiActionTextView

Comment: `android:focusable="true"` solved my problem

Comment: For future, if somebody is using Kotlin and wants to have full control over the clickable text with callback - I wrote an article about it to have extension function for `TextView` - https://link.medium.com/TLq6s8ltc3

Comment: For Deep linking see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667164/2914140.

Answer (score 1347, accepted):

Buried in the API demos, I found the solution to my problem:

File *Link.java*:

```
    // text2 has links specified by putting <a> tags in the string
    // resource.  By default these links will appear but not
    // respond to user input.  To make them active, you need to
    // call setMovementMethod() on the TextView object.

    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I removed most of the attributes on my TextView to match what was in the demo.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtCredits"/>
```

That solved it. It is pretty difficult to uncover and fix.

**Important**: Don't forget to remove `autoLink="web"` if you are calling `setMovementMethod()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution has a side effect when used with EditText. It disables action bar onLongClick and positions a cursor at the beginning of EditText.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but why would you ever do this with an EditText?

Comment: Turns out only setMovementMethod is needed to achieve the goal.

Comment: Thanks for this, been pulling my hair out all day on what should have been a simple task! In case anyone needs to implement this on the Master-detail fragment template provided by the SDK these days, I did it like this in the onCreateView method of the DetailFragment Activity:
         if (mItem != null) {
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.factsheet_detail)).setText(mItem.description);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.factsheet_detail)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }

Comment: This worked great for me as well, thank you so much!!  I do have one question - the whitespace area to the right of my links, after the closing `</a>` tag, is also clickable and therefore making it difficult to scroll through my list of results.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This is the best way... and don't forget you can create a new LinkMovementMethod like so:  setMovementMethod(new LinkMovementMethod() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(

Comment: Just as a commment, i have seen some Samsung Galaxy S3 with OS 4.3 that crash when the "setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())" is used, so just take that into account, i had to create a validation before adding it

Comment: Same here. Note that if setMovementMethod() is called, it is necessary to remove autolink="web" in the XML file, or else link won't work. Thanks for the comment

Comment: android:linksClickable="true" in textview is by default clickable.No need of mentioning out in textview tag.

Comment: also make sure you don't have android:autoLink="web", as setting this along with using LinkMovementMethod won't work.

Comment: Just use the "autoLink" attribute in your xml
for eg: android:autoLink = "web"

Comment: Maybe using autoLink="web" in your textview should do the trick, have you tried it ?

Comment: Using this code the link is clickable but after clicking it i get a dialog/Fragment with title "Open with" and in description it states "No apps can perform this action."

Comment: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Have found this to be the simplest, and most reliable solution. autolink does not work, even when testing with and without "linksClickable=true". It formats the URL but it does not launch the link. Google, why is this a mess. +1

Comment: if URL starts with a capital letter then it's not working 
ex: Https://syakt.wordpress.com or HTTPS://ME.COM

Comment: "autoLink" attribute does not work on all the devices means, If you have not inserted sim card in the phone then it does not work. I tried all the workarounds but finally I found this case. Otherwise we can display phone number with country code prefixed. I have just shared my findings.

Comment: But how do I add style to the a tag? I tried but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 592):

I'm using only `android:autoLink="web"` and it works fine. A click on the link opens the browser and shows the correct page.

One thing I could guess is that some other view is above the link. Something that is transparent fills the whole parent but don't displays anything above the link. In this case the click goes to this view instead of the link.

Comment: Added more info above.  Could it be the way I am defining the string as <string name="txtCredits"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></string>?  Looks like this is allowed but it's not working for me.

Comment: if you use linkify auto you don't need the a href part. The OS will take the string parse it for urls and converts every url to a clickable link. But this won't result in the word google being linked to google.com. It would display www.google.com as link.

Comment: using autolink works perfect for me too, plain textview without parent at all.

Comment: android:autoLink also works great for linkifying phone numbers, addresses, and e-mail addresses (or all of the above).

Comment: No it's not, because this answer doesn't work if you wan't to use an anchor tag with a display text different from the URL

Comment: This is very helpful. I need it for calling so i use the `android:autoLink="phone"` and it works :)

Comment: Yeah, it works!. You can change the link color using this attribute in xml. `android:textColorLink="#03A9F4"`

Comment: I prefer `android:autoLink="all"` for every kind of link and add `android:linksClickable="true"` to be more "secure".

Answer (score 463):

After spending some time with this, I have found that:

- `android:autoLink="web"` works if you have full links in your HTML. The following will be highlighted in blue and clickable:

> - Some text `<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`
> - Some text `http://www.google.com`

- `view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` will work with the following (will be highlighted and clickable):

> - Some text `<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`
> - Some text `http://www.google.com`
> - Some text `<a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>`

Note that the third option has a hyperlink, but the description of the link (the part between the  tags) itself is not a link. `android:autoLink="web"` does **NOT** work with such links.

- `android:autoLink="web"` if set in XML will override `view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` (i.e.; links of the third kind will be highlighted, but not clickable).

The moral of the story is use `view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` in your code and make sure you don't have `android:autoLink="web"` in your XML layout if you want *all* links to be clickable.

Comment: setMovementMethod doesn't work with second option you mentioned ie http://www.google.com.. any update?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `<a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>` won't work for autoLink. For so many answers on SO, this is the only one which mentioned it. Thank you!

Comment: setMovementMethod doesn't work for plain text urls... like https://www.google.com/

Answer (score 109):

The above solutions didn't work for me, but the following did (and it seems a bit cleaner). 
First, in the string resource, define your tag opening chevrons using the HTML entity encoding, i.e.:

```
&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">Google&lt;/a>
```

And *not*:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

In general, encode all the chevrons in the string like that. BTW, the link must start with `http://`

Then (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1999441/194825)) set this option on your TextView:

```
 android:linksClickable="true"
```

Finally, in code, do:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.string_with_links)));
```

That's it. No regular expressiones or other manual hacks are required.

Comment: This will create an HTML Parser everytime this code is executed. Be aware of that if you use this to create links inside a list item or at other performance critical places in your app. During creation of a listitem this increases the execution time of my getView Methods off 50%

Comment: Also note spaces in the URL must be replaced with `%20`

Comment: You can avoid the entity encoding problems by wrapping your string in the `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` tag.

Comment: WORKS for me, thank you. Not working with ```<![CDATA[...]]>``` tag.

Comment: This should be the answer! Worked perfectly well with my native app

Comment: Worked like a charm for me

Comment: Android Studio is telling me that `fromHtml` is deprecated.

Answer (score 90):

I simply used this:

```
Linkify.addLinks(TextView, Linkify.ALL);
```

It makes the links clickable, given [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html).

Comment: This answer is the best. Works on every Android version and we just need to add that method when the text in set in the TextView. Bonus : it allow us to add customizable links clickable

Comment: Really simplest and best answer. it works for email/web at same time.... thanks man!!!

Comment: Use LinkifyCompat if you need some of the newer advanced features

Comment: Good, it makes urls without `<a href...` clickable

Comment: It also makes all "html" tags inside work accordingly, e.g. <b>...</b> etc.

Comment: Thanks! Highlights a link and makes it clickable (29 API emulator). But for http/https links (no myapp:// variants for Deep Linking). Instead of `TextView` you should insert your real textView id.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: This should be the one true accepted answer.

Comment: Except now .ALL is deprecated starting on 33

Answer (score 74):

If you want to add an HTML-like link, all you need to do is:

- add a resource HTML-like string:

  ```
    <string name="link"><a href="https://www.google.pl/">Google</a></string>
  ```
- add your view to the layout with *no* link-specific configuration at all:

  ```
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/link"
       android:text="@string/link" />`
  ```
- add the appropriate MovementMethod programmatically to your TextView:

  ```
    mLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
    if (mLink != null) {
      mLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
  ```

That's it! And yes, having options like "autoLink" and "linksClickable" working on explicit links only (not wrapped into HTML tags) is very misleading to me too...

Comment: +1 You're right. There should be an option to enter a pattern your self so that this is matched. This way it's pretty dumb.

Answer (score 68):

The following should work for anyone who is looking for a combination of text and hyperlink within an Android app.

In `string.xml`:

```
<string name="applink">Looking for Digital Visiting card? 
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.themarkwebs.govcard">Get it here</a>
</string>
```

Now you can utilise this `string` in any given `View` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/getapp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_600"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="@string/applink"/>
```

Now, in your Activity or Fragment, do the following:

```
TextView getapp =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.getapp);
getapp.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

By now, you don't require to set `android:autoLink="web"` or `android:linksClickable="true"` using this approach.

Comment: This works well, but when yo press back from the web opened, only close the browser, but not return to the app.

Comment: Important: Don't forget to remove autoLink="web" if you are calling setMovementMethod().

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly on my project.

Answer (score 55):

I added this line to the `TextView`: `android:autoLink="web"`

Below is an example of usage in a layout file.

layout.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLostpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20px"
    android:text="@string/lostpassword"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDefaultpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20px"
    android:text="@string/defaultpassword"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

string.xml

```
<string name="lostpassword">If you lost your password please contact <a href="mailto:support@cleverfinger.com.au?Subject=Lost%20Password" target="_top">support@cleverfinger.com.au</a></string>

<string name="defaultpassword">User Guide <a href="http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/">http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/</a></string>
```

Answer (score 38):

**I hope this will help you;**

```java
String value = "<html>Visit my blog <a href=\"http://www.maxartists.com\">mysite</a> View <a href=\"sherif-activity://myactivity?author=sherif&nick=king\">myactivity</a> callback</html>";
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

text.setText(Html.fromHtml(value));
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: This works great. Also make sure you remove `android:autoLink=?` from your `TextView`.

Comment: This is what finally worked for me. Valid HTML and not using `android:autoLink=?` is important!

Comment: For Xamarin, the word shows but is not underlined and can't be clicked using the above and NOT these parameters: autoLink, linksClickable

Comment: For Xamarin setting those and setting Text or setting TextFormatted also yields the word but its not clickable nor blue/underlined. Removing the autoLink also fails. Removing only linksClickable also fails. Removing both also fails.

Comment: helloWorld.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml (linkURL); with and without those also fails. (not linked, not blue, can't be clicked)

Comment: Those are failed using the "normal" html as listed above in this proposed solution. Escaping the HTML with &gt; etc leads to garbage (markup shown) when using TextFormatted and when using text when liunksCLickable is set but autoLink is not.

Comment: using autoLink="web" without linksClickable and with HTML escaped did not work also. With HTML not escaped, it is garbage but at least the link can be clicked. Duh, back where started.

Comment: Xamarin issue: tv.Text can only be set to string and toString on Html.FromHTML (an ISpanned) is a string of only the label and not the link info. Similarly, tv.SetText is not valid as it is in Java. Seems to be some issue in the Xamarin mapping?

Comment: Here is a Xamarin example. Does not work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555862/how-to-hyperlink-textview-in-c-sharp-android

Comment: adding the <html>  tag is the key difference for this solution.

Comment: Try adding style to the a element, it doesn't work, can't change it's color or remove underline

Answer (score 30):

The easiest thing that worked for me was to use [Linkify](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html)

```
TextView txt_Message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_message);
txt_Message.setText("This is link https://www.google.co.in/");
Linkify.addLinks(txt_Message, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

And it will automatically detect the web URLs from the text in the textview.

Comment: True, but they won't be clickable.

Comment: The links are clickable.

Answer (score 26):

You only need to add this in the text view in XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```

Answer (score 25):

**Manage Linkify text color also**

[image]

```
tv_customer_care_no.setLinkTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
tv_customer_care_no.setText("For us to reach out to you, please fill the details below or contact our customer care at 18004190899 or visit our website http://www.dupont.co.in/corporate-links/contact-dupont.html");
Linkify.addLinks(tv_customer_care_no, Linkify.WEB_URLS | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
Linkify.addLinks(tv_customer_care_no, Linkify.ALL);
```

Answer (score 23):

**By using [linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html):**

**Linkify** takes a piece of text and a regular expression and turns all of the regex matches in the text into clickable links:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("http://example.com");
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Don't forget to

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is a very one-line Android code to make phone and URL selectable from textView no matter what the string is and what the data is. You don’t need to use any HTML tags for this.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText("some URL is www.google.com phone 7504567890 another URL lkgndflg.com ");

// Makes the textView's Phone and URL (hyperlink) select and go.
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

Answer (score 22):

Richard, next time, you should add this code under TextView at the layout XML instead.

```
android:autoLink="all"
```

This should be like this.

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/txtCredits"
    android:id="@+id/infoTxtCredits"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:linksClickable="true">
</TextView>
```

You don't need to use this code (`t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`) in order to make the link clickable.

Also, here's the truth: as long as you set the *autoLink* and the *linksClickable*, don't forget to add this at **String.xml** file so that the clickable link will work.

```
<string name="txtCredits"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></string>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The link is clickable indeed, but the whole string is displayed, not just "Google". In fact, none of the answers here or combination thereof works so far.

Comment: Is your device or emulator internet enabled and set it to ON (wifi) or have LAN connected, @Violet Giraffe?

Comment: It is. I never managed to make links clickable using just XML attributes, had to resort to Java code for that. Which is no big deal, but not nice.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Violet, sure wish someone figured this out.

Answer (score 15):

I noticed that using `android:autoLink="web"` thus

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```

worked OK for URLs but since I had an e-mail address and phone number that I wanted to link as well, I ended up using this line `android:autoLink="all"` like this

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:autoLink="all"/>
```

and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is correct, *but* it will mean that phone numbers, maps, email addresses, and regular links, e.g., `http://google.com` without href tags will *no longer* be clickable since you can't have an autolink in the XML content.

The only complete solution to have *everything* clickable that I have found is the following:

```
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml(myString);
URLSpan[] currentSpans = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), URLSpan.class);
SpannableString buffer = new SpannableString(text);
Linkify.addLinks(buffer, Linkify.ALL);
for (URLSpan span : currentSpans) {
    int end = text.getSpanEnd(span);
    int start = text.getSpanStart(span);
    buffer.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
}
textView.setText(buffer);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And the TextView should *not* have `android:autolink`. There's no need for `android:linksClickable="true"` either; it's true by default.

Comment: for me it worked without this, the accepted answer worked fine @Kelly can you tell the android version and device on which you got the issue?

Comment: Doesn't work for `myapp://` schemes (for Deep Linking).

Comment: The syntax highlighting seems off. E.g. near "`text.length()`". Is it?

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your EditText:

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: Oh, that works. God, Android documentation is hell.

Comment: yeh , glad to help 

Answer (score 12):

Be sure to **not** use `setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL)` when using `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` and `Html.fromHTML()` on properly formatted `HTML` links (for example, `<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>`).

Answer (score 12):

Use this...

```
TextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.twitter.com/"));
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                    
                });
```

And add a permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: This will work, but bear in mind the app may not need Internet permission beyond this clickable TextView. Maybe overkill in those cases

Comment: Does it really relate to the question?

Comment: This wasn't relevant to the question.

Comment: This will never fail!

Comment: I like this method as it allows us to have just the anchor text show rather than the full URL. The anchor text can also be styled eg colored green and underlined.

Comment: Thanks! Works for Deep linking (`myapp://` scheme).

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me among all suggested.

Answer (score 12):

You need only this:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Insert this line into a TextView that can be clickable with a reference to the web. The URL is set as a text of this TextView.

Example:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewWikiURL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="http://www.wikipedia.org/"
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

Answer (score 9):

This is how I solved clickable and *visible* links in a TextView (by code)

```
private void setAsLink(TextView view, String url){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(url);
    Linkify.addLinks(view, pattern, "http://");
    view.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://" + url + "'>http://" + url + "</a>"));
}
```

Comment: but I'd like to see the text and when clicking the text it redirect to the link (opened by the browser)? This solution doesn't solve that, does it?

Answer (score 9):

Use the below code:

```
String html = "<a href=\"http://yourdomain.com\">Your Domain Name</a>"
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

Answer (score 8):

`[Tested in Pre-lollipop as well as in Lollipop and above]`

You can get your HTML string from the backend or from your resources files.
If you put your text as an resource string, make sure to add the `CDATA` tag:

```
<string name="your_text">![CDATA[...<a href="your_link">Link Title</a>  ...]]</string>
```

Then in code you need to get the string and assign it as HTML and set a link movement method:

```
String yourText = getString(R.string.your_text);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else {
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourText));
}

try {
   subtext.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
} catch (Exception e) {
   //This code seems to crash in some Samsung devices.
   //You can handle this edge case base on your needs.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason you're having the problem is that it only tries to match "naked" addresses. Things like "www.google.com" or "http://www.google.com".

Running your text through [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) should do the trick. You have to do it programmatically, but it works.

Comment: The links in the TextView are a different color than other text in the string, so I think they're being recognized as links.  They're just not clickable :-(

Answer (score 6):

I had to hunt this down in a couple places, but I finally got this version of the code to work.

File *strings.xml*:

```
<string name="name1">&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">link text1&lt;/a></string>
<string name="name2">&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">link text2&lt;/a></string>
```

File *myactivity.xml*:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

File *myactivty.java* (in onCreate()):

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);

tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.name1)));
tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.name2)));
tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
tv2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This will create two clickable hyperlinks with the text `link text1` and `link text2` which redirect the user to Google.

Answer (score 6):

Create an extension method on SpannableString:

```
private fun SpannableString.setLinkSpan(text: String, url: String) {
    val textIndex = this.indexOf(text)
    setSpan(
        object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply { data = Uri.parse(url) }.also { startActivity(it) }
            }
        },
        textIndex,
        textIndex + text.length,
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
}
```

Use it to make string in your TextView clickable:

```
    myTextView.apply {
        movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()

        val googleUrl = "http://www.google.com"
        val microsoftUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com"

        val google = "Google"
        val microsoft = "Microsoft"

        val message = SpannableString("$google & $microsoft").apply {
            setLinkSpan(google, googleUrl)
            setLinkSpan(microsoft, microsoftUrl)
        }

        text = message
    }
```

Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: In case others have the same problem: I had a hard time getting this solution to work, before realizing I had missed the line on movementMethod. Adding it did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

If using an XML-based TextView, for your requirement you need to do just two things:

1. Identify your link in the string, such as "this is my WebPage."
   You can add it in the XML content or in the code.
2. In the XML content that has the TextView, add these:

   ```
    android:linksClickable="true"

    android:autoLink="web"
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Add CDATA to your string resource

Strings.xml

```
<string name="txtCredits"><![CDATA[<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>]]></string>
```

Answer (score 5):

I just wasted so much time to figure out you have to use getText(R.string.whatever) instead of getString(R.string.whatever)...

Anyway, here is how I got mine working. With multiple hyperlinks in the same text view too.

```
TextView termsTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.termsTextView);
termsTextView.append("By registering your account, you agree to our ");
termsTextView.append(getText(R.string.terms_of_service));
termsTextView.append(", ");
termsTextView.append(getText(R.string.fees));
termsTextView.append(", and the ");
termsTextView.append(getText(R.string.stripe_connected_account_agreement));

termsTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/termsTextView"/>
```

String example:

```
    <string name="stripe_connected_account_agreement"><a href="https://stripe.com/connect/account-terms">Stripe Connected Account Agreement</a></string>
```

Comment: This is so much more straight-forward and easy to use. I have multiple links with custom text working in a dynamically added TextView because of this. This needs the most upvotes possible. Been breaking my head over Spanned strings, custom TextViews and HtmlCompat.fromHtml methods. Thank you so much @luca992.

Answer (score 4):

Autolink phone did not work for me. The following worked like a charm,

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emergencynos);
String html2="<br><br>Fire - <b><a href=tel:997>997</a> </b></br></br>";
tv.append(Html.fromHtml(html2));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: What is *"Autolink phone"*?

Answer (score 3):

I use the autolink to "auto underline" the text, but I just made an "onClick" that manages it (I ran into this problem myself).

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:text="@string/twitter"
    android:onClick="twitter"/>

public void twitter (View view)
{
    try
    {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/onaclovtech"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

It doesn't require any permissions, as you are passing the intent off to apps that manage those resources, (i.e., the browser).

This was what worked for me.

Comment: You are not making a link that is clickable, you are just putting the whole TextView clickable... That's not the question.

Comment: Agreed, but sometimes a workaround that works, is the same thing. Clearly 5 years after the most popular answer has been written, this was still a problem, and its been 6 months sice i had the same problem, but ended up with a different but working solution.

Answer (score 3):

My code was like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:text="@string/forgot"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

My Java code was like this:

```
/*TextView action*/
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,forgot.class));
            }
        });
```

This just points the link to another activity. But that link is clickable and works smoothly. Tested in Android Studio 1.5 (Preview)

Comment: Why in the past sense? Is it no longer like this?

Comment: This code will work... I was just pasting an old code

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```java
package com.stackoverflow.java.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.method.MovementMethod;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView;

public class HyperlinkTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    public HyperlinkTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HyperlinkTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HyperlinkTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    /**
     * Set default movement method to {@link LinkMovementMethod}
     * @return Link movement method as the default movement method
     */
    @Override
    protected MovementMethod getDefaultMovementMethod() {
        return LinkMovementMethod.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Now, simply using `com.stackoverflow.java.android.HyperlinkTextView` instead of `TextView` in your layout files will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having issues with strings reading from XML content and assigning dynamically.

In case you are using text from a *strings.xml* resource, it seems that the **HTML tags gets stripped out**.

So you have to use `<![CDATA[**your string with click links**]]>` in the *strings.xml* file to convert it to HTML using **Html.fromHtml(string)**.

Comment: Could you please give an example, I have this error. For example, how to convert this in order to use with dynamically content: <string name"myStringWithParameter">  %1$s hello <a href="www.google.com">google<a/></string>

Comment: @Andrew - You can use strings inside cdata like this 

<string name="sample_html"><![CDATA[%1$s Check <a href="https:// www.google.com">google<a/>]]></string>
then replace with
val replacedString = String.format(getString(R.string.sample_html), "Tada..")
and set from Html
textViewHtml.text = Html.fromHtml(replacedString, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
also add to make it clickable 
textViewHtml.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() --- (Your google link was not correct .. add https )

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add links to your TextView with Android's [Linkify library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify).

For example, let's add a clickable legal notice TextView to our Activity.

strings.xml

```
<string name="text_legal_notice">By continuing, you confirm that you have read, understood and agreed to our %1$s and %2$s.</string>
<string name="text_terms_conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</string>
<string name="text_privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</string>
```

Activity class

```
final String termsConditionsText = getString(R.string.text_terms_conditions);
final String privacyPolicyText = getString(R.string.text_privacy_policy);
final String legalText = getString(
        R.string.text_legal_notice,
        termsConditionsText,
        privacyPolicyText
);
viewBinding.textViewLegalNotice.setText(legalText);

Linkify.addLinks(
        viewBinding.textViewLegalNotice,
        Pattern.compile(termsConditionsText),
        null,
        null,
        (match, url) -> "https://policies.google.com/terms"
);
Linkify.addLinks(
        viewBinding.textViewLegalNotice,
        Pattern.compile(privacyPolicyText),
        null,
        null,
        (match, url) -> "https://policies.google.com/privacy"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin you can do

```
binding.yourTextView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

your string should be in HTML format

Answer (score 0):

As the [databinding](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) is out, I'd like to share my solution for databinding TextViews supporting HTML tags with clickable links.

To avoid retrieving every textview and giving them html support using `From.html` we extend the TextView and put the logic in `setText()`

```
public class HtmlTextView extends TextView {

    public HtmlTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HtmlTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HtmlTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.toString()), type);
        this.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

I've [made a gist](https://gist.github.com/Sebring/b86c00b4a0a09abbc14c) which also shows example entity and view for using this.

Comment: `Html.fromHtml()` should never be called from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Not to beat this to death, but here is what is happening under the covers with Linkfy, etc.  You'll notice that setText() takes a CharSequence. Linkify, etc. converts the String to Spannable and adds Spans.  Spannable indirectly inherits from CharSequence, just like String, so it works with setText().  With Spannables you can mix and match Spans and do all sorts of interesting things.  Here's a simple example.

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTextView)
val span = SpannableStringBuilder(getString(R.string.linkText))
textView [0, textView .length] = URLSpan("https://myWebiste.com/")
textView.text = span
textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Just a note, the Kotlin syntax is very slick but it obfuscates the Spannable.setSpan() call, which is where the magic happens.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution using Kotlin Programming Language**

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWeb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val tvWeb = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtWeb)
        val tvEmail = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtEmail)
        val tvPhone = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtPhone)

        //for web address
        tvWeb.setText("Please visit us: www.google.com")
        Linkify.addLinks(tvWeb, Linkify.WEB_URLS)

        //for email address
        tvEmail.setText("Please Email Us:abcdef@gmail.com")
        Linkify.addLinks(tvEmail,Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES)

        //for phone number
        tvPhone.setText("Please Call Us: +4672123456")
        Linkify.addLinks(tvPhone,Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS)
    }
}
```