# Android: Clickable TextView with Linkified links

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I have a TextView in my layout which has an attribute "clickable=true" set in XML. This is to allow it behave like a button with both text and icon. 
Now, I add to that TextView HTML text via call HTML.fromHtml(), and apply                                               Linkify.addLinks after that.

The problem is: in such configuration, links are not clickable. Is there any suggestion, how to allow user click on links, other from creating custom TextView-based class?

Thanks

Comment: You want a TextView that is clickable, with links inside of it that are also clickable?  That sounds like it could lead to a poor user experience, you might want to rethink your UI design.  Have someone with big fingers try to hit exactly a tiny button within a small button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add an attribute "android:autoLink="web"" to the textview

Answer (score 0):

Also, I have struggled hours against the `TextView` before realizing that

```
<resources>
  <string name="mytext">Going to <a href="http://www.google.fr/">Google</a> is linkifed but NOT clickable</string>
</resources>
```

But this is:

```
<resources>
  <string name="mytext">Go to http://www.google.fr/ is linkified and clickable</string>
</resources>
```

In both cases, the link is recognized and styled accordingly.

Comment: There is a workaround, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable/2746708#2746708