# Android TextView - Clickable Links and Clickable View

Tags: android, html, textview

I have a TextView, in which I am putting some HTML content using Html.fromHtml(). The TextView has an onClick() method, which is used to perform several actions. Sometimes the HTML that is in the TextView contains links, which are recognised as links, but are unclickable. I can make them clickable, but then that stops the onClick method.

My question is, is there a way that, if the user clicks on a link then the link opens, but if the user doesnt click on a link then the onClick() method for the TextView is called, rather than it being  either one or the other for every click.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251745/android-clickable-textview-with-linkified-links

Comment: Does look like a similar problem but that solution doesn't work for me

Comment: its too late to answer this but if some one needs more clear answer its at [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) to do it in code:

```
Linkify.addLinks(yourTextView, Linkify.ALL);
```

Comment: Unfortuantely that doesnt help. The links are in the HTML, and they do appear as hyperlinks (blue underlined), but they're just not clickable.

Comment: are they in standard html link (`<a href="">some link</a>`) format?

Comment: Yes. I think its that the listview handles the click. Which I want it to do, but not if its a link thats been clicked.

Comment: ahaan so you are using it in a ListView.... try setting `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to your ListView...