# Adding a web link to a TextView widget

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I would like to know if and how it is possible to add a web link to a TextView widget. In my app, i show some text and adjacent to this text an image. I would like to insert a clickable internet link in the text. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to set the **android:autolink** property.

```
<TextView
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="http://www.google.com" />
```

Comment: Very straight forward and easy to add. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it by code

```
private void setAsLink(TextView view, String url){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(url);
        Linkify.addLinks(view, pattern, "http://");
        view.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://"+url+"'>http://"+url+"</a>"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your web link is different from the text you are showing in the TextView:

The TextView in your layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_with_hidden_clickable_link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/string_with_text_and_link"/>
```

Your string in your resource file:

```
<string name="string_with_text_and_link">
    <a href="http://any_web_site">The text in your TextView</a>
</string>
```

And in your Java class:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_with_hidden_clickable_link))
    .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

> NOTE: `http://` in the string resource is necessary.