# How to make text go to webBrowser/Url

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to make my text view clickable in a way that when the user taps it it will send him to our website/url.
Can someone show me how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

Well are you looking for the user to enter their URL of choice and then a corresponding "go" button will take them to the URL? If so, I would implement a TextView in your XML file. After that, make sure you implement the TextView you created within the apps java file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to implement the OnClickListener and put the listener to the TextView

`tvExample.setOnClickListener(this);`

In the OnClick method you need to launch an `Intent` with the Url from the webpage.

```
String url = "http://example.com";  
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));  
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: so i add a onclicklistiner and add the id after i add this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about this here[enter link description [here](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/). 
You will find information on that website and example aswell.

Good luck,
Arkde