# set TextView with string which contains a clickable HTML link

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` in layout

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/homepage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I would like to set a **string** with **HTML link** in this TextView, and **make the link clickable** (open the link on browser when clicked). I tried the following:

I defined the string in resource, the string contains a HTML link to google website:

```
<string name="home_page">please go to &lt;a ref="www.google.com">www.google.com!&lt;/a>.
```

In my Activity:

```
TextView homepage =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.homepage);

String text = getString(R.string.home_page)
CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);

homepage.setText(styledText.toString());
```

The result is **please go to www.google.com**  , but the **www.google.com** is not a clickable link. How to make it clickable? (I mean open the link in browser when clicked)

Comment: use a clickable span for this purpose. http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

Don't forget to use `http://` before `www.` otherwise you will get `ActivityNotFoundException`

```
TextView homepage =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.homepage);
homepage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
homepage.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#696969'> please go to <a href=\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\">"+"http://www.google.com"+"</a></font>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

below code work for me:-

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_post_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

[Autolink inside a TextView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246366/autolink-inside-a-textview-in-android)

http://alltechsolution.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable/

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-textview-autolink-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

All the code to do this is described in this blog.. check it
http://android-developers.blogspot.fi/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html

Answer (score -1):

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/links"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoLink="web" 
        android:text="www.google.com" />
```

Try this code it's worked for me.