# Material Design - how to implement text with clickable links?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I need to implement a textview with dynamic links, when user can jump into another activity. My first idea was to use spannableText but the is a better way to do that in material design? I was looking something with Chips, but I wasn't able to find any example. Implementing something by my own is not an issue but it want to see if there is already an accepted way to do that.

Comment: please refer following link
[your answer is already given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246366/autolink-inside-a-textview-in-android) hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you Sagar, I know already the typical way to do that, my question if there is a better graphic way to do that compatible with material design