# Detecting click event on a particular text in TextView with marquee

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I am setting a text in textview.And it is marquee text.Not just the text, it is an array of text concatenated one after another and added to textview.I want that if i will click any text then that text(or word) will be shown in a dialog box.First of all is it Possible anyhow.I tried to use Spannable from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345768/android-how-to-set-the-portion-of-the-text-is-clickable) first answer.but it's not working as per my requirement as i have marqueeing text.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you replace the marque with something more useful? :) You may wrap your textView into a horizontal scroll view. Then you have a thread (AsyncTask) that scrolls the text, using ScrollView.setScrollX() just as marquee does.

Can you guess, what comes next?  Use spans, as suggested by the link, you quoted!

Comment: So u know there is horizontal scrollview and how asynttask will scroll using ScrollView.setScrollX()? plz add some code ?