# HTTP links in alert dialog not working

Tags: java, android, http, textview, android-alertdialog

I tried following the following example to make an HTTP link in my TextView in my alert dialog clickable, but it does not work:

[How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

The only way I can get it to work is if I put the text of the link directly into my string and put `android:autoLink="web"` into my TextView.  But I do not want to see the whole link, just the name.

Here is where my dialog is created:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    switch (id) {
    case DISCLAIMER:
            final View disclaimerView = factory.inflate(R.layout.disclaimer_dialog, null);
            final TextView dtv = (TextView) disclaimerView.findViewById(R.id.disclaimer_body);

            dtv.setText("v"+versionName+"\n\n\u00A9"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)+" "+"Developer\n\n" +
                getString(R.string.alert_dialog_disclaimer_body));

            dtv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());                

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)                
                .setView(disclaimerView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here is my TextView located in `R.layout.disclaimer_dialog`:

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/disclaimer_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Here is my string resource:

```xml
<string name="alert_dialog_disclaimer_body">This application was developed and written by me.\n\nGraphs use AChartEngine licensed under <a href="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0">Apache License 2.0</a>.\n\nThe rest goes here.</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation to [TextView.setText(CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) explains:

> Sets the string value of the TextView. **TextView does *not* accept HTML-like formatting, which you can do with text strings in XML resource files.** To style your strings, attach android.text.style.* objects to a SpannableString, or see the Available Resource Types documentation for an example of setting formatted text in the XML resource file.

And following their suggestion, [Formatting and Styling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) explains, under the *Styling with HTML markup* heading, how you can have both HTML markup and formatting codes.

I think the easiest thing in your situation would simply be to adjust your layout to have your copyright notice in one View that you use as you already are, and put the disclaimer below in a second View that you simply leave alone:

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/disclaimer_body"
    android:text="@string/alert_dialog_disclaimer_body"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: Hmm, I think you might also need `formatted="false"` in your string element: `<string formatted="false" name="alert_dialog_disclaimer_body">`.

Comment: @jsstp24n5 I realized what the real issue was and rewrote my answer.

Comment: Thank you... after struggling with the html formatting documentation, your suggestion about 2 textviews is exactly what I pursued before I even saw it. Thanks again.