# Android Marquee TextView Clickable Links

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I have a TextView in my app. It is a marquee text. I want to make this marquee text's links are clickable. How can i do this?

Thanks for help.

Edit: My codes:

Xml:

```
android:id="@+id/marquee_text"
android:autoLink="web"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
android:text=" "
```

Java:

```
marqueeText.setLinksClickable(true);
marqueeText.setText(marquee);//marquee is a string
```

Answer (score 1):

- Via [XML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink):

  ```
  android:autoLink="web"
  ```
- Via [Code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask%28int%29):

  ```
  txtView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS)
  ```

Comment: still not working :/ Links are being clickable, if i longclick on textview and set input method.

Comment: `Links are being clickable, if i longclick on textview and set input method`. Is that what you want? the links to be clickable?

Comment: yes, i want the links that inside marquee text to be clickable.

Comment: yes, i mean when i click on the link, no web page is opening :/

Comment: I just tried your code in the question and it is working fine with me!

Comment: I am trying it again and again, but doesn't work with me :/ But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try Linkify to add link to textview.

```
mTextSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSample);
String text = "Visit my blog jtomlinson.blogspot.com You can see Marquee also here";
mTextSample.setText(text);
//jmt: pattern we want to match and turn into a clickable link
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("jtomlinson.blogspot.com");
//jmt: prefix our pattern with http://
Linkify.addLinks(mTextSample, pattern, "http://");
```

For More Info [Click Here](http://jtomlinson.blogspot.in/2010/03/textview-and-html.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:autoLink="web"` on your `TextView` in your layout XML, or you can use the solution here:

[How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: i've tried this already. if i long click on textview and then set input type, i can click link.