# TextView - OnClick - Android

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to add onclick to some portion of a textview? For instance my code goes like this,

```
String content = "Hello this a test.. For more details contact @Peter";
someTextView.setText(content);
```

I would like to add an onClick event for "@Peter". Is that possible?

TIA.

Comment: you want to add `onclick` to the whole `textview` or just **@Peter**?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable or you can do it with Spannables and IntentSpan.

Comment: @RKN add `onclick` for just **@Peter**

Answer (score 7):

Simple: -)

```
SpannableString link = makeLinkSpan("@Peter", new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Peforme Click
        }
    });
String content = "Hello this a test.. For more details contact";
someTextView.setText(content);
someTextView.append(link);
```

And `makeLinkSpan()` method is

```
private SpannableString makeLinkSpan(CharSequence text, View.OnClickListener listener) {
    SpannableString link = new SpannableString(text);
    link.setSpan(new ClickableString(listener), 0, text.length(), 
        SpannableString.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return link;
}
```

**`ClickableString`**  Class

```
private static class ClickableString extends ClickableSpan {  
    private View.OnClickListener mListener;          
    public ClickableString(View.OnClickListener listener) {              
        mListener = listener;  
    }          
    @Override  
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        mListener.onClick(v);  
    }        
}
```

Comment: Now, you have only Click event for "@Peter" text. Not for complete TextView. Means your word @Peter is linked..

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @user370305 for the response.. However he missed some code snippet in his answer.. For the benefit of others, I'm pasting the entire code that worked for me,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView someTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.someTextView);

        String content = "Hello this a test.. For more details contact";
        someTextView.setText(content);

        SpannableString link = makeLinkSpan("@Peter", new View.OnClickListener() {          
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Do something here..
                }
            });
            someTextView.append(link); 
        }
        makeLinksFocusable(someTextView);
    }

    private void makeLinksFocusable(TextView tv) {
        MovementMethod m = tv.getMovementMethod();  
        if ((m == null) || !(m instanceof LinkMovementMethod)) {  
            if (tv.getLinksClickable()) {  
                tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());  
            }  
        }  
    }

    private SpannableString makeLinkSpan(CharSequence text, View.OnClickListener listener)                 {
        SpannableString link = new SpannableString(text);
        link.setSpan(new ClickableString(listener), 0, text.length(), 
            SpannableString.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return link;
    }

    private static class ClickableString extends ClickableSpan {  
        private View.OnClickListener mListener;          
        public ClickableString(View.OnClickListener listener) {              
            mListener = listener;  
        }          
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            mListener.onClick(v);  
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In you Xml add this,`android:clickable="true"`

in you activity use like this,

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(){

    }
}
```

Comment: This will add click event for the entire textview.. I would like to add it for only some portion.. in the case mentioned above for **@Peter**

Comment: @Peter: Refer this link, i hope this may help you http://adilatwork.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-how-to-make-only-part-of.html

Answer (score 2):

This is possible wither using Java code:

```
someTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(){
        //Do Stuff
    }
});
```

But first make sure that you set it clickable.

```
someTextView.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: I would like to `onclick` for only some portion of the textview and not for the entire textview.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SpannableString str = new SpannableString("@Peter");
str.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, 0, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Then append `str` to your TextView.

You also need to call `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` on your TextView