# How to modify text style of link TextView?

Tags: android, xml, hyperlink, textview

In my menu I have a **`TextView`** with a link to *Google Calendar*, my problem is that I can't modify the color and the underline of this one.

Because **`My TextView`** should be gray and not underlined, but it is ***blue*** and ***underlined***, as a web link. I try many solutions, but nothing succeed...

If someone could help me, please !

Comment: Post what you've tried

Comment: use custom spannable

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya I tried some things with xml, but I think it's not possible to modify with xml.

Comment: So I'll try to understand and try the @AntonKazakov advice

Comment: have you tried [like this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout)

Comment: @ruben Yes but it's still underline

Comment: @ruben Finally it's Ok, thank's a lot !

Comment: In fact it doesn't work. the text style is the good one but the link has disappeared

Comment: @simonvancoillie you should post your code!

Answer (score 0):

With that, My text is perfect, white and not underlined, but the link doesn't works

```
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OngletAgenda);
    t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Mon Agenda");
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 10, content.length(), 0);
    t2.setText(content);
```

Comment: what about [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: @ruben Already did it, but I found a new sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143879/9480041 but now the problem is the color, I'm near the issue but it's frustrating