# How to hyperlink TextView in C# android?

Tags: c#, android, textview

I would like to display a some text that when clicked will redirect me to a website. I am writing by android app with C# (Xamarian studio).

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/rsstitle"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.rsstitle).Text = values [position];
//values[position] contains a title string eg "Google"
```

links[position] contains a uri eg "https://www.google.co.nz/"

How do I make it so that "Google" is displayed but when clicked directs to https://www.google.co.nz/

Answer (score 2):

Found my solution:

```
String linkText = "<a href=\"" + RSSActivity.links [position] + "\">" + values [position] + "</a> ";

link.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(linkText);
link.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
```