# android adding links to dynamic texts in Edittext

Tags: android, hyperlink

I have an Edittext fild in my android application, I will update the content dynamically.I need to make all web address appearing in the Edittext box clickable and need to load the web page in default browser.how can i do this in my code?

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:editable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Instead of Edittext you can use TextView and [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2734270/2345913)

Comment: @CRUSADER I don't have html links to add in the Edittext, only some text with or without a webaddress,I made the Edittext instead of Textview because user can also copy the content in the view and paste somewhere,if he like