# can i add anchor tag in android list items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Here I am adding `ArrayList` to the layout dynamically based on results of my web server program of DB. `ArrayList` is adding to layout which is fine. But I want send another layouts if I click one of the listed items (here is another layout which is used to show full details of the listed items  ).

```
public class FullDetails extends ListActivity  {

    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    int clickCounter=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_details);
       adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
         setListAdapter(adapter);
         fullItems(null);
    }

    JSONArray all=new JSONArray();
    String size;

    public void fullItems(View v) {
        String result = "";
         InputStream is=null;

        try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://norten.com/adrd/ejrpg.jsp");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                     is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //Adding list item dyanmically to layout
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    size=json_data.getString("size");

                   for(int j=0;j<Integer.parseInt(size);j++){


                      all=json_data.getJSONArray("res"+j);

                      listItems.add(all.get(0)+" \n venue:"+all.get(1)+" Price:"+all.get(3));
                   }

                }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }





        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly..? want to apply anchor tag functionality of HTML to android TextView?? then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Comment: create a class to hold the tag and then put it into Adapter, not use a simple String.

Comment: @Lokesh any thing which works on android which makes go to another layout when i click on the any one of  displayed list.

Comment: @longkai Thanks for your reply.will you show me how to add class to adapter in my code?

Comment: well, what you mean is you don' t know how to go to the FullDetails when clicking the list items? you want a anchor to go there?

Comment: @longkai yes.Any functionality  which makes to go full details layout.

Comment: but i viewed your fulldetail' s code, it' s not clear... why your FullDetails which you want to go after clickting an item has the full items?

Comment: @longkai In above code i  am showing all events with only events names.when i click on the event name the full details of event should be displayed.