# I dont get a clickable link in TextView Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, string, textview

Hi I cant get my link clickable. What is it I'm doing wrong? The >This app< is blue and underlined but not clickable.

```
<string name="footer"><a href="http://google.com">This app</a> is cool</string>
```

this is my string in XML

```
<TextView
    style="@style/ContentGroupTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:autoLink="web" 
    android:text="@string/footer" />
```

Comment: possible to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Comment: You're missing this directive `android:linksClickable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add HTML-like link, all you need to do is:

add a resource HTML-like string:

```
<string name="link"><a href="https://www.google.pl/">Google</a></string>
```

add your view to the layout with NO link-specific configuration at all:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:text="@string/link" />
```

add appropriate MovementMethod programmatically to your TextView:

```
 mLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
 if (mLink != null) {
   mLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
 }
```

Comment: add appropriate MovementMethod programmatically to your TextView... where do I fill this code? In which file?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this..
     <string name="about">
    <![CDATA[
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="text-align:justify;">
        <a href="http://google.com">This app</a>
    </body>
    </html>
    ]]>
</string>

    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about)));
```

Comment: In which file would I have to add your suggestion? Im a learning developer and not very experienced

Comment: define the string in strings.xml file.

Comment: Ok and where do i add; tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about)));  ?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace android:autoLink = "web" to All. It may help you..

```
               <TextView
                style="@style/ContentGroupTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                 android:autoLink="all" 
                android:text="@string/footer" />
```