# How to set text as link in android and pass that text to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

To set text as a link i followed this [[How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable])

But when i click on that text it should pass that text to another activity . How to do that.

For example i have set few text in one activity as links , so when i click on that link it should go to another activity and even that text data should be passed.

Please somebody help me with it. I am new to android development.

Comment: Are you referring to text link rendered via webview or you have a text in a label and would want to click a button and then have the text launch another activity and transferred to that new activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple just define this under you onclick functionality where you intent to next activity

**Define Onclick like this under OnCREATE**

```
  YourTEXT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 next();
            }

        });
```

**Then write this function anywhere in your activity**

```
    public void next()
   {

  String strMessage = YourTEXT.getText().toString());

// so on you can directly set values
// you have to just set values in string                      

  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextactivity.class)   
  i.putExtra("new_variable_name",strMessage);


  startActivity(i);
```

}

**Then in your next activity retrieve it via**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String var="";

      if (extras != null)
      {

        String value= extras.getString("new_variable_name");       
        value= var;

      }
```

**Then you can use the string *var* in your next activity**

Answer (score 0):

When you use Linkify to add links to text, pass in a scheme with something like below:

```
private static void linkifyUsername(TextView text){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@([a-zA-Z]|[\u4E00-\u9FA5]|[0-9]|_|-)+");
    String scheme = "com.example.app.profile://";
    Linkify.addLinks(text, pattern, scheme);
}
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml, put in an intent-filter as below for the activity which will accept that link (use the same scheme):

```
<activity android:name=".Profile" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="com.example.app.profile" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

now clicking on the link in the text will lead to the Profile activity, in Profile activity you can use code below to retrieve the link:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
```