# How to convert textview as link in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have created a login page which consists of a username password login button and a signup button which should be a link. I want to convert this signup(text view) to a link that can be  navigated to the next page. How would I do that? For example if I click on **don't have an account? sigup**,it should be navigated to  welcome.java..

Please help....

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_form_rounded"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button_rounded"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/signup"
        android:autoLink="web" 
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.internationalization12;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getActionBar().hide();
    }



}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: That question, is it really Android?

Comment: i have tried by adding android:autoLink="web"..its not working

Comment: so u needed to open a url while click on the textview

Comment: I want to navigate to the next page on clicking signup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setOnTouchListener to the TextView. Here I give you an example:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener { 
      private TextView tv1; 

      @Override 
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1); 

        tv1.setOnTouchListener(this); 

      } 

      @Override 
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 

       // HERE YOU HAVE TO CHECK WHICH ID IS SELECTED, IF YOU HAVE MORE THAN ONE,
       //   AND WHICH EVENT HAS THE USER DONE.

      // IN YOUR CASE.. OPEN WEBSITE LIKE THIS:


Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);

        return true; 
      } 
    }
```

Comment: This one of many many ways, and also over-complicated. `onClick` would be much easier, since with your method, you still have to check motionEvent.

Comment: @Jaume Colom Ferrer thnks it worked.Can you tell me tell how can i include hover while clicking signup?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
package com.example.internationalization12;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView txtSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         txtSignUp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_sign_up);
         txtSignUp.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Dont have account?SignUp</u>")
         txtSignUp.setOnClickListener(signUpListener);
        //getActionBar().hide();
    }
    public OnClickListener signUpListener=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class));
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Can you tell me tell how can i include hover while clicking signup?

Comment: No there is no any hover event in android.Hover is the event of web

Comment: Above code will display the underline below text and navigate you to welcome.java

Comment: If you want underline when clicking on text then put txtSignUp.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Dont have account?SignUp</u>") this line inside onClick event

Answer (score 0):

you can try Linkify [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)

```
textview.setText("www.androiddeveloper.com");
Linkify.addLinks(textview, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```