# Android:Click on URL from an activity

Tags: android

I want to put a clickable URL in my activity so when the user click that url the device browser triggers and the url opens normally. Any help about that please....

Comment: Do you want to open it in a browser or in a web view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: No i dont want to use the webview if it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to use **Linkify**

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
textView.setText(someContent);          
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
```

[detailed example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.htmlhttp://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html?m=1)

[Android Linkify api doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)

> *error in findViewById I don't know why*

Id of view is  defined  in  yr XML

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/yourTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"       
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

> *cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' it is a fragment from a navigation drawer not an activity maybe the error in that point*

In fragment  use:

```
getView().findViewById(id) ;
```

or in case u need  activity reference:

```
getActivity().
```

Comment: error in findViewById I don't know why

Comment: What error? U need define your text view Id in XML or create new via code

Comment: I did that and no error at all with the id but there is an error in "findViewById" itself there is a red line under it

Comment: @Mero_Android  message text  of  error  when u hover over it

Comment: cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' it is a fragment from a navigation drawer not an activity maybe the error in that point

Comment: When in fragment u call it Ive update my  answer

Comment: thank you very much I finally did it only add (getActivity) before findViewById and everything solved

Comment: @Mero_Android u welcome

Answer (score -1):

Create a textView with id "clickableUrl", with the text of your choice (in exemple "Click here to open in browser")

Then in the onCreate method of your Activity, put this code :

```
TextView clickableText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickableUrl)
clickableText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               String url = "http://www.google.com";
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
               startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

It should start the google.com webpage on the device browser when you click on the TextViex.

Please ask me if you need any help.