# HyperLink in a TextView inside a Scrollview not clickable in Android?..Whats the Solution?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, scrollview

TextView is inside a Scroll View..

```
                       <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/meer_informative_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                            android:autoLink="all" 
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

Code in Main Activity::

```
final TextView meer_con = (TextView)  
findViewById(R.id.meer_informative_content);
meer_con.setText("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `MoveMentMethod` in your textview to make it clickable

like this:

```
meer_con.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Also put your url in anchor tag and treat URL as html:

`meer_con.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href="http://www.google.com">Google.com</a>"));`

Comment: yes ,,i have added setMovementMethod..But still it's not clickable.

Comment: I noticed you didn't put anchors around your url. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks For Reply,,,,i also put anchors around the URL,,But Still its not clickable...Any improved suggestion,,,,,Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you used `Html.fromHtml`? I have updated the answer to use anchors correctly.

Comment: yep,,,i used Html.fromHtml().

Comment: Actually,the scrollview contains the Viewpager and LinearLayouts ,,and my textview is inside the linearlayout after the viewpager but inside the scrollview,,,,I tested with hardCoded string,,,textView.ClickListener is not working on this textview,it does not show me Toast on click even with simple text(without Link)...is there any solution suggested? Very Thanks

Comment: post a separate question with your code and expected results.

Comment: Here is the new Question,,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011774/scrollview-contains-viewpager-and-linearlayouts-with-textview-inside-the-linearl

Comment: can you try using

Comment: private void touchListener(View view) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //action to be done
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }