# Scrollview contains ViewPager and LinearLayouts with TextView inside the LinearLayout,But TextView ClickListener is not working(Not Clickable)?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, clickable, clicklistener

```
        <nl.vogelbescherming.wadvogels.util.HackyScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <nl.vogelbescherming.wadvogels.util.HackyViewPager
                android:id="@+id/profiles"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/infoBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/voorkomen_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="MAIN HEADER"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/voorkomen_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="3"
                            android:text="MAIN HEADER"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/trefkans_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="MAIN HEADER"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/trefkans_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="3"
                            android:text="MAIN HEADER"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/grootte_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="MAIN HEADER"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/grootte_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="3"
                            android:text="MAIN HEADER"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Het is een adembenemend schouwspel; een jagende boomvalk 
die met hoge snelheid en een luide &apos;tsjak&apos; een libel uit de lucht 
grijpt. Boomvalken zijn gespecialiseerd in het vangen van 
vliegende prooidieren Lees meer..."
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/in_shadow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/meer_informative_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Snavel"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </nl.vogelbescherming.wadvogels.util.HackyScrollView>
```

---

Main Activity Code:

```
    TextView meer_con = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meer_informative_content);
    meer_con.setText("Hi i am chawal Text,,,Try to CLick me:@");
    meer_con.setClickable(true);
    meer_con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MEER_TAG","meer_informative_content_text_Displayed");
            System.out.println("meer_informative_content_text_Displayed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain more your question. It will be helpful to better understand your question

Comment: Actually,the scrollview contains the Viewpager and LinearLayouts ,,and my textview is inside the linearlayout after the viewpager but inside the scrollview,,,,I tested with hardCoded string,,,textView.ClickListener is not working on this textview,it does not show me Toast on click even with simple text(without Link)...is there any solution suggested? Very Thanks