# How to make links in textview clickable

Tags: android

How to make links clickable in text view. This is the problem

(1). `view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` 
this works only when textview contains link(anchor tag/href) like this:

```
<a href="http link">Go to Google</a>
```

it does'nt work when textview contains link like this:
http link

(2). While `android:autoLink="web"` 
this works only when textview contains link like this:
http link
it does'nt work when textview contains link like this:

```
<a href="httplink">Go to Google</a>
```

What to do when textview contains both types of link.
Please help.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Search on #SO.this type of questions already asked .

Comment: android:autoLink="web" this properties only work if your link contain http:// or https://

Comment: post your code you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="http://www.google.com"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorLink="@color/white"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
```

in xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

or you can use String

```
 htmltext=Html.fromHtml(htmltext)
```

then set this htmltext to textview

```
textview.setText(htmltext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
     String mobile = "12345678";
```

Set this text with link and click listener

```
     SpannableString mobile_underline = new SpannableString(mobile);
     mobile_underline.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, mobile.length(), 0);
     textviewID.setOnClickListener(new PhoneNumberClickListener());//Implement custom listener to write respective code of click listener
```