# Long Click on CardView with LinkMovementMethod

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `CardView` with a `TextView` inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:translationZ="0dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Inside the `TextView` There are `HTML` links, and therefore assign a `LinkMovementMethod` to it.

```
viewHolder.comment.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

When I long click on the `CardView`, I want it to bring up a Contextual Action Bar. This works fine if I long click anywhere in the CardView that isn't overlapped by the `TextView`. But If I long click on the `TextView` (not a link) it does not detect the long click.

Is there anyway for just the links to be clickable, but the rest of the `TextView` not just disregard it and use the card views on click instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Comment: Sorry I may have explained this badly, but basically, I only want the HTML links to "Consume" the click, not the entire textview as it does now using LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()