# How to make TextView selectable, select and copy like this link?

Tags: android

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SR28jj4nTEkthis is link][1]

i want to learn about how to make TextView selectable, select and copy like this link, but this link have died a can't go to the web via this link, so please help me, thanks you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: Add android:clickable="true" to TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer stays in this link.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/12/make-textview-selectable-select-and-copy.html

Let me know if you need anything else.