# How to set a TextView in Android as a link? I don't want to display the link but something else like "click me"

Tags: android, url, textview

I am trying to add a URL on my Android App login page which redirects user to recover password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: I'd like to argue that this question is not a duplicate of the question linked above. This question is more about getting users to the password recovery page through interaction, not just making a TextView clickable. I've demonstrated in my answer below what I believe the author is really getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to show the user a text looking like a url so that when the user taps on it you can redirect him to a web page. 
    In your xml layout, declare a TextView with text attribute set

```
<TextView android:id = "@+id/txt"
...

android:text= "Click me !">
```

And in your activity class,

```
txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(txt.getText());
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, txt.length(), 0);
txt.setText(content);
txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome. You can accept/upvote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in terms of how a web page would do it, but it doesn't necessarily have to be a text link like a web page. You could simply have a button (or any view really) that takes the user to password recovery when touched.

As an example, this is how you would do it with a button in your layout:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = "http://www.your-password-recovery-page.com";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

This will launch the default browser of the device and navigate to your password recovery url.

Comment: Thank you for your help  NoChinDeluxe :) but the requirement is strictly a link and not a button.