# make word clickable in edit text

Tags: android

I want to make a some words highlighted and clickable in an EditText like it does when you misspell something. For example, if I type "flight" when I am typing, I want it to be highlighted and clickable.

Here is a snippet of the code and the XML:

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textplace);
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/textplace"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: No there's no such direct way to do this but if you want to open a hyperlink then yes it is possible. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Comment: what I want is to make some words the user type to be highlighted so the user can click it to lunch another screen or activity. I have some words on my mind but the problem is how to link them to Edit Text so any time the user types such words they get hyperlinked and clickable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

`String str = Html.fromHtml("<a href="#>" + str + "</a>");`

method to create a hyperlink on a string where `text` is the part of the contents of the EditText that you want linked.

Comment: what I want is to make some words the user type to be hyperlinked so the user can click it to lunch another screen or activity. I have some words on my mind but the problem is how to link them to Edit Text so any time the user types such words they get hyperlinked and clickable