# Set clickable link with placeholder text in textview within a viewpager

Tags: android

I want to set a text with a clickable link in my TextView.

Expected output: *More info can be found [here](http://google.com).*

The String looks like this:

```
String text = "More info can be found <a href='http://google.com'>here</a>."
```

I set it to the TextView like this

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This should work as is but since my Textview is in a Fragment within a ViewPager clicking it won't do anything.

Anyone has experienced the same issue?

Comment: use spannable text

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable), there are so many answers, give it a try and check which one work for you

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I have, those solutions won't work in my case since the ViewPager seems to bug the normal solutions.

Comment: @Madhur I'll try with spannable text, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your xml attribute

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Comment: Autolink will only work for links that are fully visible in your textView e.g. "More info can be found on http ://g oogle.com". Mine is hidden under the label "here" thus it won't do anything.

Comment: ok. have you tried assiging a attribute android:clickable="true"

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to fix it