# How do I open a browser on clicking a text link in TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, string.xml

I made an activity that has some text. I made a link clickable in `TextView` but and it is working fine (link is visible with underline).

But when I click the link it says `Unfortunately app has stopped responding` Here is my code.

The `TextView` code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:text="@string/google" />
```

The `Java` code (in `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` ):

```
 TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home); //txt is object of TextView
    txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The `string.xml` code:

```
<string name="google">
    <a href="www.google.com">Home page</a>
</string>
```

This is what my app shows,

[image: App screenshot]

Now if I click **Home Page** link the error message saying `Unfortunately app has stopped not responding appears` What should I do?

***Please help!***

Comment: please add crash log

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Answer (score 17):

Just add following line in your textview xml.

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Comment: My java code doesn't have onClickListener() you should give that code too. Please give full answer from now on if you answer any question t anyone. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to those who helped me by their answers

This is what the complete answer looks like.

In the `TextView` of `activityname.xml` write `android:autoLink="web"`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:autoLink="web
    android:text="@string/google" />
```

In the `java` file write create `onClickListener()`

```
TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home); //txt is object of TextView
    txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
```

No changes in the `string.xml` file

Thanks to @AdnanAmjad @sarvesh @Mikejess and to **the guy who deleted his comment**

Comment: I noticed you pass in the uri to the intent manually. What if you have a long text view with multiple links? How would one pragmatically find which link was clicked and extract that specific url from string resource file?

Answer (score 5):

```
text_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     String url = textView.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);

});
```

Comment: It did not work

Comment: I found the missing key thanks

Comment: This is the one that worked for me; I just added due implementation methods that are lacking in this example for the OnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one it is working for me i have check the result both for textview and button you can use it and at the place of text you can replace the link

```
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text=" Click To Send Email "
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#cf1414"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/emailbutton"/>
```

Comment: My java code doesn't have `onClickListener()` you should give that code too. Please give full answer from now on if you answer any question t anyone. Anyways, thanks for the help.