# how to make clickable url link in TextView on android without using java

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Here I used clickable URL on `Textview` and it works. But how can I set clickable and highlighted Text with Open URL with a browser. It's possible from Android XML OR kotlin without using java code like `setText(Html.fromHtml(""))`.

```
String value = "<html>Visit Web <a href=\"http://www.domainname.com\">mysite</a> View</html>";
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(Html.fromHtml(value));
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: Doing it «without using java» is impossible because `TextView` is written in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
<TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="http://www.example.com"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

It's No required declear layout id and no code from java side. it's works from xml

Use Autolink

1. - For website `android:autoLink="web"`
2. - For call  `android:autoLink="phone"`
3. - For email `android:autoLink="email"`
4. - For map  `android:autoLink="web"`
5. - For all   `android:autoLink="all"`

Answer (score 5):

This property works for you 
TextView: android:autoLink="web"

here is an example Layout 
 **layout.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLostpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:text="@string/lostpassword"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDefaultpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:text="@string/defaultpassword"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

**string.xml**

```
<string name="lostpassword">If you lost your password please contact <a href="mailto:support@cleverfinger.com.au?Subject=Lost%20Password" target="_top">support@cleverfinger.com.au</a></string>

<string name="defaultpassword">User Guide <a href="http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/">http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/</a></string>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add this attribute to your TextView `android:autoLink="web"`
 e.g

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="https://www.google.co.in"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add line to the TextView:

```
`android:autoLink="web"`
```

Like this

```
<TextView
        ................
        ................
        android:autoLink="email"
       .................
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Aakash Verma suggested use `android:autoLink="web"`.

but it will change your textColor. To over-come this also add `android:textColorLink="your_text_color"` to you TextView.

Your TextView should look like.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="https://www.google.co.in/"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

If you still want to do in in java

```
myUrl= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myUrl);
myUrl.setText("https://www.google.co.in/");

Linkify.addLinks(myUrl, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
myUrl.setLinkTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

**EDIT:**

[image] [image]

Happy Coding

Comment: What is the look of a link or how would it get distinguished from the normal text if it continues with the same colour?

Comment: if you just use `android:autoLink="web"` it will change your text color to your Accent color. and if you haven't specified Accent color.. it will be changed to Sky Blue (Default). `android:textColorLink="your_text_color"` wiill work as `android:textColor` for your link. i'm uploading SS for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:autoLink="web"` in your TextView's xml. It should automatically convert urls click-able (if found in text)

Also, don't forget `android:linksClickable="true"`. I don't think that you need to set `html` tag like you did, just the `<a href>` tag...

Comment: it will change textcolor tho.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using text from strings.xml resource, it seems that the **html tags gets stripped out**.

So you have to use `<![CDATA[**your string with click links**]]>` in the strings.xml to convert it to html using **Html.fromHtml(string)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Textview:

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```