# How to create feed post view like Twitter with dynamic links?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-imageview, textview

I'm trying to achieve something like this image [image twitter tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Sc5.jpg). The user creates tweets with hash tags and links in it and Twitter app converts into click able links. Normal TextView can't achieve that. How do I create something like that? Please provide technical details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
You can use **ClickableSpan** to achieve this like this

```
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        SpannableString str1 = new SpannableString("click me");
        str1.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, str1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, str1.length(), 0);
        str1.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, str1.length(), 0);

        SpannableString str2 = new SpannableString("demo String 2  ");
        builder.append(str2);
        builder.append(str1);

        Textview.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        Textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```