# Does a hyperlink in android studio need internet permission?

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-manifest, android-permissions, user-permissions

I have hyperlinks in my new android app:

```
<string name="additionURL"><a href="www.example.com">More Information</a></string>
```

Does this require this line of code in the manifest file?

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I was unable to find this information anywhere.

Comment: I'm not aware that `<a>` is a valid HTML tag for a string resource. That being said, that should not require the `INTERNET` permission by default, as clicking on it at most would bring up a Web browser, and the browser is what needs the permission.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your answer. Yes `a` is a valid tag, and it works. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Comment: Make sure you test that thoroughly on your oldest supported API level. I'm fairly certain that `<a>` *didn't* work early on in Android, and I don't know when they added support for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I checked API 16 and it works. Since that is the lowest SDK my app supports, I think I am safe