# Change the link to the custom string that can be clicked on TextView

Tags: java, android

I have link https://google.com . i want that link just change to string "google"

showed in the TextView is "google"

but actually in google have link https://google.com . and possible to clicked

i have xml :

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/social"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
android:text="in here social"/>
```

i have java class :

```
 TextView social = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.social);
 String text = "<a href='https://google.com'> Google </a>";
 social.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and in the xml this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/txtCredits"/>
```

In the xml remove the autolink if you are calling `setMovementMethod()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can save your url in tag, like this:

```
social.setTag("https://google.com");
```

when you want to get url do this:

```
String url = (String) social.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah my problem is solved

in your XML :

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/social"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
android:linksClickable="true"
android:text="@string/social"/>
```

in Your Values String

```
<string name="social">in here social</string>
```

and in your java class

```
TextView mSocial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.social);
mSocial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(https://google.com));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

make your TextView as String "Social"
but if TextView clicked can go to google.com