# To run a simple link with LinkMovementMethod in android

Tags: hyperlink, xamarin.android, textview

How to run a simple link with the following command?

```
<TextView
    android:text="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />


TextView textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1); 
textView.TextFormatted = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml("https://www.google.com"); 
textView.MovementMethod = Android.Text.Method.LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
```

These work:

```
   textView.TextFormatted = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml("<a href=\"" + "https://www.google.com" + "\">google</a>");
       textView.TextFormatted = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml("<a href=\"" + "https://www.google.com" + "\">https://www.google.com</a>");
```

This also does not work:

```
<TextView
    android:text="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />

 textView.TextFormatted = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml("<u>" + "https://www.google.com" + "</u>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LinkMovementMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.text.method.linkmovementmethod?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) only works for the links in the text  .

In Html `<a>` represents a hyperlink to a url , but `<u>` is not hyperlink ,it is just an underline .

Avoid using the  element where it could be confused for a hyperlink .

Comment: Hello and thank you. I saw [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-to-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable). Jeshurun wrote that `view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); will work with the following (will be highlighted and clickable):`
My question was `Some text http://www.google.com`   So we must use `<a>`?

Comment: Yes, `<a>` is the only option .