# How to add clickable link in string xml file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, hyperlink

How do I make a link within string resource to be clickable and open a web page when the user clicks it?

```
<string name="about" translatable="false">
  Click <annotation font="lato_bold">. 
  <a href="https://google.com/">here</a></annotation> 
  for more information
</string>
```

I could do this with `TextView` but I don't know how to do it with string resources.

Thank You.

Comment: Where r you showing the String resource ?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/2734270/11754047

Comment: @ADM I am showing them in TextView.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from coding:

**Kotlin:**

```
var result:Textview = findViewById(R.id.myTextview)


result!!.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
            
            val text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google.com</a>"
            result!!.text = Html.fromHtml(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<string name="about" translatable="false">
  Click <annotation font="lato_bold">. 
  <a href="https://google.com/">here</a></annotation> 
  for more information
</string>
```

to

```
<string name="about"> 
    <a href="https://google.com/">here</a>
</string>
```

You can directly use `anchor tag` inside string tag