# Android how to clickable Addresses in TextView

Tags: android, textview, google-mlkit, linkify

When there is any address in string, showing in `TextView`, need to be clickable and open on maps.

I've tried `tv.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL)`. It is not working for all addresses. [image]

Any other way that's make clickable and link all addresses in `TextView`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make links in a TextView clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-to-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: I've tried all of these, no thing is working :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple on click listener.

```
 textView.setOnClickListener {
 //open google maps

 }
```

and for text to make it look like a link you can use:

```
    <string name="underline_text"><![CDATA[<u>underlined text</u>]]></string>
```

Also, you can use blue text color (#0D6EFD) to make it more professional.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Intent.ACTION_VIEW to open google map from your app. Something like this:

```
    tv.setOnClickListener {
        val address = tv.text
        val content = "geo:0,0?q=$address"
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(content))
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Here I'm using Kotlin, convert java if you want