# Change color of Hyperlink in AlertDialog

Tags: android

Normaly this behavior isn't dramatic but on a Samsung Galaxy S the default AlertDialog background is blue and a normal formatted link (blue) disappears. 
Unfortunately the below code does not change the color of the link.

Has anyone a idea?

```
public void showClickableDialog(String title, String msg) {
    final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(msg);
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);

    final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setIcon(
                    R.drawable.logo).setTitle(title).setMessage(s).create();

    d.show();

    // Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()
    TextView textView = ((TextView) d.findViewById(android.R.id.message));
    // Next Line unfortunately does nothing
    textView.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the following in my `style.xml` in order to make a link orange:

```
<item name="android:textColorLink">#FF9900</item>
```

So I assume in code you just need to do this (for some reason the [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLinkTextColor%28int%29) name is inconsistent with the XML property):

```
textView.setLinkTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```