# hyperlink a url in android

Tags: android

I have a text in an view in android.I want that my url should be hyperlighted and It should have different color other that background color..Can anyone tell,Whats the procedure?
Thanks in advance

Regards
Tushar

Comment: @Tushar can you please give more details , which view you are using? whether the text is entered by user or are you setting to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an autolink attribue on your text field:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/TweetTextView"
              android:autoLink="web"
```

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_autoLink) for all options.

Answer (score 0):

[Change color of Hyperlink in AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542210/change-color-of-hyperlink-in-alertdialog)