# Can't get HREF to work in Android strings.xml

Tags: android, href

I'm trying to add a link to a Twitter profile in an about box. 'Regular' links such as email address and web address are handled by

```
android:autoLink="email|web"
```

in about.xml, but for a Twitter profile page I need to use html code in my strings.xml. I've tried:

```
<string name="twitter">Follow us on &lt;a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/mytwitterprofile"&gt;Twitter: @mytwitterprofile&lt;/a&gt;</string>
```

which renders html markup on the about box.

I've also tried:

```
<string name="twitter">Follow us on <a href="http://www.twitter.com/mytwitterprofile">Twitter: @mytwitterprofile</a></string>
```

which display the text "Follow us on Twitter: @mytwitterprofile", but it is not a hyper-link.

How do I do this seemingly simple task!?

Cheers,
Barry

Comment: how do you add the string to your box?

Comment: See if you find this post useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/android-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog

Comment: TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.about_content);
  textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  textView.setText(getString(R.string.about_text, getString(R.string.twitter), getString(R.string.email_address), getString(R.string.website)));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that the `TextView` does not support `<a>` tags. AFAIK, it only supports basic formatting such as `<b>`, `<i>` and `<u>`. However, if you supply `android:autoLink="web"`, the following string:

```
<string name="twitter">Follow us at twitter.com/mytwitterprofile</string>
```

Will turn `twitter.com/mytwitterprofile` into a proper link (when set via XML like `android:text="@string/twitter"`; if you want to set it from code, you'll need the `Html.fromHtml` method someone else posted in an answer).

Comment: Thanks for that. It's not perfect but it'll do. Incidentally, I didn't need the Html.fromHtml either (my about.xml has android:autoLink="email|web" though)

Answer (score 10):

The problem is your "a href" link tags are within strings.xml and being parsed as tags when  strings.xml is parsed, which you don't want. Meaning you need to have it ignore the tags using XML's CDATA:

`<string name="sampleText">Sample text <![CDATA[<a href="www.google.com">link1</a>]]></string>`

And then you can continue with `Html.fromHtml()` and make it clickable with `LinkMovementMethod`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHolder);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.sampleText)));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: I think to close the CDATA section it should be ]]> instead of just ]].     <string name="sampleText">Sample text <![CDATA[<a href="www.google.com">link1</a>]]></string>

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure how to link using 'strings', but you could set text of the EditText or TextView using fromHtml...

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google Link!</a>"));
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this just displays "Google Link!", not a hyperlink.

Comment: The text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); should make it into a clickable link?!

Comment: Unfortunately not, just regular text.