# Hyper Links Inside An AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, html, rss, android-alertdialog

Im having an android app that takes info from RSS (in pure html form, including p tags, and a href tags).

Here's the code that creates the alertdialog:

```
Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(rss.getDesc()));
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("אישור", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
alertDialog.show();
```

Now, as I have already mentioned, the `rss.getDesc()`-method brings full html code.

As you can see, I have managed to handle the html, but the hyper links don't work...
Here's an example of html: (ignore the language)

```
<p dir="rtl" align="right">כידוע לכם, עומר וייסבלום זכה בתחרות &quot;המורה של המדינה&quot; ובימים אלו מסייר בבתי ספר בארה&quot;ב במשלחת ישראלית שיצאה במסגרת הזכייה.</p>
<p dir="rtl" align="right"> מצ&quot;ב לינק לכתבה על עומר בעיתון בי&quot;ס תיכון אמריקאי באזור וושינגטון בארה&quot;ב (Walt Whitman High School).</p>
<p><a href="http://www.blich.co.il/node/16346">הצג את ההמשך</a></p>
```

I would be glad if you can tell me what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, there is the [`Linkify`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html). As the docs read:

> Linkify take a piece of text and a regular expression and turns all of
>   the regex matches in the text into clickable links. [...]

Since you want to enable links in a Dialog, you'll want to use a [`Spannable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) for your text and pass it to `Linkify`s [`addLinks()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks%28android.text.Spannable,%20int%29).

An example (and similar question) can be found here: [How can I get clickable hyperlinks in AlertDialog from a string resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/android-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog/3367392#3367392)