# Hyperlinking the Phone number in AlertDialog of Android

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, android-alertdialog

I have an  AlertDialog having the text **"For more information, Please Call 1-800-200-1000"**.

Here is my Code for the Alert Dialog Display while clicking on the ListView Item :

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final SpannableString s = new SpannableString("1-800-200-1000");
        Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
        ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

          builder.setMessage("For more information, Please Call "+s)
           .setCancelable(true)
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();
        }});
```

**Here i wish to hyperlink the "1-800-200-1000" and while clicking on this, another dialog for call function should be implemented.**

Here is my AlertDialog for Call Function:

```
    final Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Call?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       Intent dial = new Intent();
            dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ Phone));
                                        startActivity(dial); 

                                    }
                                });
                                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Activity will continue",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
```

**Please help me in two problems:**

**1.How to hyperlink the Phone number in the First Dialog?**

**2.how to embed the Call AlertDialog while clicking the Hyperlinked Phone Number?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/android-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog
may help u...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this one:

```
Spannable spans = (Spannable) text;
ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"+ url));
}
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    //override link-centric text appearance
}
};
int index = (text.toString()).indexOf(url);
spans.setSpan(clickSpan, index, url.length() + index,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Yes you can Use Linkify also.