# Clickable Hyperlinks in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

This is my static inner class for creating an AlertDialog inside my MainActivity class:

```
public static class AboutDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static AboutDialogFragment newInstance() {
        AboutDialogFragment frag = new AboutDialogFragment();
        return frag;
    }  

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_about)
                .setTitle(R.string.about)
                .setMessage(R.string.about_message)
                ..........
                .create();
    }
}
```

And I'm showing it when you press a menu item which is inside MainActivity:

```
case R.id.about:
        DialogFragment aboutFragment = AboutDialogFragment.newInstance();
        aboutFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "about_dialog");
        // Make links clickable
        ((TextView) aboutFragment.getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        return true;
```

I'm trying to make the links in the message text clickable using the commented line.

I found this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/android-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog) and it has worked for me when using a regular Dialog (no fragments).
 However, this is the first time I have tried using it on a DialogFragment and I always get a NullPointerException when trying to find the view.

I've also tried `aboutFragment.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message)` but that returns null as well.

Maybe I am calling the code too early/in the wrong place?
Any ideas would be great!

EDIT: Just tried `((TextView)  v.getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`
and
`((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` in onCreateView() and also tried in onCreateDialog() without success.
Still getting null pointer exception...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hopefully you've already figured this out but I just did this same thing and wanted to document it somewhere. Put this in your `DialogFragment` class:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ((TextView) getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.message))
            .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe I am calling the code too early/in the wrong place?

That's my suspicion. Is there any reason you can't do your "make links clickable" inside your `onCreateDialog()` method?

Comment: See my edit. I've tried in both onCreateDialog() and in onCreateView() after calling View v = super.onCreateView(...) and it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

As the time progressed, adding some updated inputs to the query.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupView(view)
}    

private fun setupView(view: View) {
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener({ v -> dismiss() })
        toolbar.title = "New Message"
        view.tvTitle.text = arguments?.getString("title")
        view.tvBody.autoLinkMask = Linkify.ALL
        view.tvBody.text = arguments?.getString("body")
        view.tvBody.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }
```

Most important 2 steps in the above code (which can be used in any dialog textviews) are:

1. To Linkify
2. setMovementMethod

After this all links will work fine.