# Android link in dialog

Tags: android

How can I add a link to a dialog message?

I tried the following code, but the link doesn't do anything on onclick:

```
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(
      "Click on the  " +
      "<a href=\"http:\\www.google.com\">link</a> " +
       "to download."));
```

It didn't work for `//www.google.com` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard implementation of dialog doesn't allow you to do such fancy stuff. You need to create a custom dialog by setting a custom layout content to it. For example:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);
```

For more details, read [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/).

Answer (score 25):

Use the following code to convert your HTML markup (including clickable hyperlinks):

```
((TextView) new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Info")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
    .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<p>Sample text, <a href=\"http://google.nl\">hyperlink</a>.</p>"))
    .show()
    // Need to be called after show(), in order to generate hyperlinks
    .findViewById(android.R.id.message))
    .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: qq meer, enige met punten. gg

Comment: Simple and perfect answer!

Comment: @DIFORT I know, baddies gonna use third party libraries

Comment: @erdomester you should consider marking this as the accepted answer to provide others with the same question a more simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Linkify

```
final SpannableString m = new SpannableString(message);
Linkify.addLinks(m, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

    aDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(m)
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        doNeutralClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();

    aDialog.show();

    ((TextView) aDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/android-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog).