# Android - Hyperlink in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I would like to display a link in my AlertDialog, but after multiple attempts it still displays it as plain text.

I have tried the suggestions in the following links:
[How can I get clickable hyperlinks in AlertDialog from a string resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/how-can-i-get-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog-from-a-string-resource)

[Android link in dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095335/android-link-in-dialog)

Here is my current state:

```
     final TextView msg = new TextView(context);
    final SpannableString s = new SpannableString("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    msg.setText("BradcodeScanner app must be installed on your phone\n" +
               "click on the link below.\n\n" +s);
    msg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    info_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr_info);
    info_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("QR Location Scan")
                    .setView(msg)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    return;
                                }
                            })
                                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                                    .show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should try ClickableSpan. Try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HyperLinks work only in HTML text. So you have to:

```
msg.setText(Html.fromHtml("BradcodeScanner app must be installed on your phone</br><a href=\"" + s + "\">click here</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
mTvContent.setPaintFlags(mTvContent.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
mTvContent.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.aviary_accent_blue));
mTvContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (link.contains("http://")) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(link));
        context.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        link = "http://" + link;
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(link));
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
    }
});
```