# adding links in the message of AlertDialog on Android

Tags: android, android-maps, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

Below is the code for **AlertDialog** box. I am using this in google map. I want to add "See more" **Hyperlink** at the end of the message.. I don't know what I have missed so far to make the link work. Thanks for help in advance.

```
@Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        OverlayItem item = pinpoints.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet()+"\n\n"+Html.fromHtml("<a href=\'http://www.nip.org.np\'>See more</a>"));
        dialog.show();
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/android-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OverlayItem item = pinpoints.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet()+"\n\n"+Html.fromHtml("<a href=\'http://www.nip.org.np\'>See more</a>"));
    dialog.show();

    try {
        TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if (tv != null) tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return true;

}
```