# Android hyperlinks on TextView in custom AlertDialog not clickable

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Following my previous question I still have problems managing hyperlinks on my custom `AlertDialog` but I believe I narrowed down the problem because I think it only not works because it's  a custom dialog.

I have followed all the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/android-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view) but can't seem to bypass this situation

On `strings.xml` I have a string defined this way:

```
<string name="link_text_manual"><b>text2:</b> This is some other
  text, with a <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a> specified
  via an &lt;a&gt; tag.  Use a \"tel:\" URL
  to <a href="tel:4155551212">dial a phone number</a>.
</string>
```

If I create my dialog this way:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Data")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.info)
       .setMessage(R.string.link_text_manual)
       .setCancelable(true)
       .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });

AlertDialog welcomeAlert = builder.create();
welcomeAlert.show();
// Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()
((TextView)welcomeAlert.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

it shows like this:

[image: Image 1]

This works as expected and all clicks are clickable.

Now I want the same thing but on a custom layout.

Created a `TextView` on my `info.xml` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoDetailText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infoVersionTitle"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:padding="4dp" />
```

And this is the code:

```
    Context ctx = this;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.infoLayout));

    AlertDialog.Builder about = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    about.setView(layout);
    about.setTitle("Data");
    about.setIcon(R.drawable.info);

    AlertDialog displayInfo = about.create();
    displayInfo.show();
    // Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()
    TextView textView = (TextView) displayInfo.findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText);
    textView.setText(R.string.link_text_manual);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

With the above code it shows like this (links not clickable and even not marked as links):

[image: Image 2]

If I remove

```
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

it shows like the bellow image (Links marked as links but not clickable):

[image: Image 3]

I've also tried to use `Linkify` and `android:autoLink="web"` but the result is always the same.

`setMessage()` works but with a custom layout with a `TextView` can't make it to work.

Probably this is simple but can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Try textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(R.string.link_text_manual)); and also set android:clickable attribute to textview in xml

Comment: @hemanthkumar Thanks. Done that but is the exact same thing as image 2. Links not clickable and even not marked as links

Comment: @user370305 Thanks but its always the same. With your suggestion it's like image 2. Links not clickable and even not marked as links

Comment: @user370305 Without `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`, `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Click <a href=\"http://www.poon-world.com\">here</a> to switch on the red light.\n"));` It's like image 3. Links marked as links but not clickable. With `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` like image 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: Look at my answer. Just remove two attributes from `TextVIew` attributes from **info.xml** file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined the TextView without `android:autoLink="all"` , `android:clickable="true"` & `android:linksClickable="false"`

For info.xml TextView as below

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/infoDetailText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp" />
```

Comment: Finally. I already have tried `Html.fromHtml` but with no success. Since the only difference was the way you defined the `TextView` went back to my `TextView` and removed `android:autoLink="all" android:clickable="true" android:linksClickable="false"` Now it works even with getting the string as `textView.setText(R.string.link_text_manual);` Many Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

Anyway, your code works perfectly,...

**Code for AlertDialog:**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, null);
AlertDialog.Builder about = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
about.setTitle("Data");
about.setIcon(R.drawable.info);

// Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText);
textView.setText(R.string.link_text_manual);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
about.setView(layout);
AlertDialog displayInfo = about.create();
displayInfo.show();
```

**Code of TextView XML:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoDetailText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infoVersionTitle"
    android:padding="4dp" />
```

Removed two attributes..

```
android:autoLink="all"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: Thanks. Following @rajpara answer figured that out so marked is as the correct answer. Upvoted yours. I can't believe how long it took. It's strange how removing those attributes made it work when in all other threads they were always recommended... Anyway, many thanks for your time and efford

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setText(Html.fromHtml(String));
```

Comment: Thanks but `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.link_text_manual)));`is the exact same thing as the second image.

Comment: Also set this property for the text view.
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());