# android: Set link with <a href> in TextView

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, textview

I create a TextView dynamically and want to set the text as linkable. Text value is "[Google](http://google.com)". I referred to internet & blogs [like this,](http://jtomlinson.blogspot.in/2010/03/textview-and-html.html) which shows the same way, but I couldn't produce the expected results.

I tried different ways, but the output I see is the whole text with  text only. The code I have tried with is :

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setLayoutParams(textOutLayoutParams);
// Make Linkable
tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(l.getLeftString()));

/*SpannableString s = new SpannableString(l.getLeftString());
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
tv1.setText(s);                 
tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
*/
dialogLayout.addView(tv1);
```

In my output I see "[Google](http://google.com)" and no link. I also tried Clean project & building it again, but no success.
I am looking to see only "Google" as underlined with blue color (as default) and on clicking Google, the browser open with http://google.com.

What is lacking in my code to get the output ?
BTW For REF : I use 64bit Win 7, Java, Eclipse, Android API 8-2.2

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069811/android-hyperlinks-on-textview-in-custom-alertdialog-not-clickable/12070751#12070751

Comment: @user370305, removed Html.fromHtml, Tried with & without setClickable, but no success - still see the full text <a href.... in textview. I don't have anything in xml - dialog & TextView's are created dynamically.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I finally got it working using the following code :

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setLayoutParams(textOutLayoutParams);
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+ l.getRightString() + "\">" + l.getLeftString() + "</a>"));
tv1.setClickable(true);
tv1.setMovementMethod (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
dialogLayout.addView(tv1);
```

l.getRightString()  - contains a url like http:\www.google.com 
l.getLeftString()  - contains text for the url like "Go to Google"

RESULTS :
Text "Go to Google" on my dialog with blue color and underlined, and on clicking it the browser opens up and shwows the respective page. On returning/Exiting the browser it again comes to the app from the state where it had left.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, the setClickable(true) is not needed. But if I try to add the link with an append() to another text, it does not work :S

Comment: Important. Do not set android:autoLink="web" because with that it doesn't work!

Comment: @DawidDrozd that is very important indeed. Thanks mate, you saved me from killing myself :)

Comment: I read and tried many other solutions; this is the only one that worked for me in following map links. btw, use urlEncoder to encode your addresses - it works like a charm.

Comment: As @DawidDrozd mentioned you should not combine setMovementMethod with android:autoLink="web" (or any value), but as an extra note: I wasn't using the autoLink property but Linkify.addLinks(spannableString, Linkify.ALL) instead. This is the same, so don't combine those either!

Comment: Of all the answers on this site yours is the perfect one.

Answer (score 13):

Save your html in a string

```
<string name="link">&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">Google&lt;/a></string>
```

Set textview ID to to

```
textViewLinkable
```

In main activity use following code:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLinkable)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLinkable)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.link)));
```

Comment: Itried String s = "&lt;a href=\"http://google.com\">Google&lt;/a>";
  tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
  tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));  and what I see is "<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>"  Again no actual anchor link.

Comment: @SquireaSquire, I have tested on Emulator only of Api 2.2 & 4.1.

Comment: @Tvd i have this code in my own app and it displays a normal link (blue underline, onclick goes to website)

Comment: What is ur system config & which API r u using

Comment: @Tvd windows 7 emulator - 2.0, Nexus S 4.1 [Jellybean], Xperia Play 2.1

Comment: I am on Win 7 x64. Tried on emulator 2.2 & 4.1  API 8. The code that I got, works on both emulator versions.

Comment: Yrs it works with the code I added as answer. No other way was workable except this one.

Answer (score 7):

I was also facing the same issue I resolved using following

```
String str_text = "<a href=http://www.google.com >Google</a>";
TextView link;
link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
link.setText(Html.fromHtml(str_text));
```

for changing the link color to blue use

```
link.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: The key is the `Html.fromHtml(...)` that returns a `Spanned`

Comment: The best solution that I found so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here is my simple implementation tested up to Android N.

```
String termsText = "By registering, you are agree to our";
String termsLink = " <a href=https://www.yourdomain.com/terms-conditions.html >Terms of Service</a>";
String privacyLink = " and our <a href=https://www.yourdomain.com/privacy-policy.html >Privacy Policy</a>";
String allText = termsText + termsLink + privacyLink;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_terms_conditions)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_terms_conditions)).setText(Html.fromHtml(allText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} 
else {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_terms_conditions)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_terms_conditions)).setText(Html.fromHtml(allText));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
txtview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Pass this statement to your textview, and in string.xml set an string as

```
<string name="txtCredits"> <a href="http://www.google.com"></a></string>
```

Now pass this string name " android:text="@string/txtCredits" to your xml class where the txtview is there .

Comment: This is a clean answer

Answer (score 0):

use this code [autolink-java On GitHub](https://github.com/robinst/autolink-java)

like this

```
private String getLink(String string){

    LinkExtractor linkExtractor = LinkExtractor.builder()
            .linkTypes(EnumSet.of(LinkType.URL)) // limit to URLs
            .build();
    Iterable<Span> spans = linkExtractor.extractSpans(string);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Span span : spans) {
        String text = string.substring(span.getBeginIndex(), span.getEndIndex());
        if (span instanceof LinkSpan) {
            // span is a URL
            sb.append("<a href=\"");
            sb.append(text);
            sb.append("\">");
            sb.append(text);
            sb.append("</a>");
        } else {
            // span is plain text before/after link
            sb.append(text);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();  // "wow <a href=\"http://test.com\">http://test.com</a> such linked"
}
```