# How can I get clickable hyperlinks in my AlertDialog in my Android app?

Tags: android, user-interface, hyperlink, custom-controls, android-alertdialog

There is another question like this, except I am trying to avoid TextView, since I don't have an XML file to accompany this error message. I am trying to redirect my user to a link when he clicks on the hyperlink text. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
public void messageAlert(){
    String link = "www.google.com";
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("ErrorMessage")
    .setMessage("You have a massive error. Please go to "+ link) // hyperlink here
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_error)
    .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int n){

            }
    })
    .show();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
P.S. I am a beginner to Android

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/how-can-i-get-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog-from-a-string-resource

Comment: @LoveForDroid No its not. I don't want to use ListView

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a href the accepted answer on this link shows a good example.  [a href example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119800/android-set-link-with-a-href-in-textview)

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + "http:\\www.google.com" + "\">" + "Go to google" + "</a>"));
tv1.setClickable(true);
tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Just add this TextView to your Dialog and it will show the Go to google as a normal Hyperlink which on click will open a browser and search for http:\www.google.com

Comment: How do I add it to my dialog?

Comment: You could create a custom dialog with its own layout xml file dialog.xml there you add the textview. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) There you find an example just create first an `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);` from your layout file use this to find the textview `TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);` and do the settings after this `builder.setView(view);` and the rest stays the same as in the example.

Comment: `public void show() {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
View view= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + "http:\\www.google.com" + "\">" + "Go to google" + "</a>"));
tv1.setClickable(true);
tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new    AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
        dialogBuilder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }'

Comment: Whats `mActivity` and I don't have a dialog

Comment: mActivity is an Activity object which you have to declare before calling the function show(). `Activity mActivity;` If you have this function in your activity you can replace "mActivity" with "this" and this will show you a dialog. You only need the dialog.xml file with a TextView declared in it. with the id = textview.