# Clicking Link HTML in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a text view that is displaying some HTML and it displays correctly. If the HTML contains a link with just the URL text I can tap on the link to open it, but if the URL is attributed to other text, like this:

`<a href="https://cdn.kyfb.com/KYFB/assets/File/Federation/Across%20Kentucky/2017/January/AK_Promo_Jan_23_2017_mixdown.mp3">Listen here</a></strong></p>`

"Listen here" looks like a clickable link in my text view but it can't be selected.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;

public class BenefitDetailActivity extends BaseActivity {

    static Context context;
    TextView detailTextView;
    String descriptionText;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_benefit_details);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent detailIntent = getIntent();
        descriptionText = detailIntent.getStringExtra("description");

        detailTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.benefitText);

        Typeface kfb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond.otf");
        detailTextView.setTypeface(kfb);
        detailTextView.setTextSize(20);

        System.out.println("DESCRIPTION: " + descriptionText);
        detailTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(descriptionText));
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/benefitText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/white_text"
        android:autoLink="all" />
```

Based on the suggestions of others, I've added

```
detailTextView.setMovementMethod (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and

```
android:linksClickable="true"
```

With that, the problem is that when I add setMovementMethod(), the linked text (Listen here) is no longer displayed as a link and still can't be selected.

Comment: Have you set `setMovementMethod(new LinkMovementMethod())` for your `TextView`?

Comment: @RomanKolomenskii No I have not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: Set link with <a href> in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119800/android-set-link-with-a-href-in-textview)

Answer (score 2):

add following attribute to textview in layout file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/benefitText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:textColor="@color/white_text"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    />
```

and the add following line to on setMovementMethod.

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        detailTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(descriptionText,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        detailTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(descriptionText));
    }
    detailTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: This didn't work. After doing this my link doesn't even appear as a link.

Comment: please check updated answer, This is what worked for me for same problem.

Comment: Can't resolve symbol FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY and Can't resolve symbol N

Comment: Either upgrade your sdk to android api version 25 or remove the if condition which is for android nougat(N)

Comment: I removed the if statement but the problem is that when I add setMovementMethod(), the linked text (Listen here) is no longer displayed as a link and still can't be selected.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding `detailTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`
and `android:linksClickable="true"`. I also had to remove `android:autoLink="all"`

Comment: remove android:autoLink="all"  was the key! yaas!