# Android: Open alertdialog from part of string?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, android-alertdialog

I have a CheckBox with a string that says "I have read and understood the terms and conditions". Now I want to make the words "terms and conditions" to a link which opens a alertdialog where the terms and conditions can be read. Nothing special.

I'm thinking something in the line of:

```
<string name="cont_agree">I have read and understood the <a ref="open alertdialog">terms and conditions.</a></string>
```

Is it possible, and what should I use where it now says "open alertdialog"?
If it can't be done this way, how should I do?

**Addition:**
To open a url you would use this code:

```
<string name="cont_agree"><a ref="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a></string>
```

But how do you open a alertdialog, or say another screen, from a string? I have seen apps who does this so it is possible, of course, but how?

EDIT:
This is the code I use for the SpannableStringBuilder:

```
SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder();
text.append(getString(R.string.before));
//Now create a ClickableSpan
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) {                

                d.show(); //Here dialog will be displayed
            }  
        };
//Now append the TOS string
text.append(getString(R.string.popup));
//Declare that the "TOS" string is a clickableSpan
text.setSpan(clickableSpan, getString(R.string.before).length(),getString(R.string.before).length()+getString(R.string.popup).length(), 0); //Check on API setSpan method
((CheckBox)findViewById(yourview)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); 
((CheckBox)findViewById(yourview)).setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I still get some markers at the first "text.append" line.
Multiple markers at this line:

- Return type for the method is missing
- Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this token
- R.string.before cannot be resolved to a type
- Syntax error on token ")", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
- Syntax error on token "append", Identifier expected after this token

Comment: Check this link [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069811/android-hyperlinks-on-textview-in-custom-alertdialog-not-clickable)

Comment: Yes I saw that one, but he is trying to open links FROM an alertdialog if I'm not mistaken. I want to open an alertdialog from a regular string used in a checkbox. So I couldn't find an answer there.

Comment: I really need help with this. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: i've never tried such implementation @andysando post some code so that others can help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First setup your dialog

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
d.setTitle... etcetc
```

In your values.xml create 2 string

```
<string name="before">I have read and understood the</string>
<string name="popup">TOS</string</string>
```

Now you can use SpannableStringBuilder

```
SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder();
text.append(getString(R.string.before));
//Now create a ClickableSpan
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) {                

                d.show(); //Here dialog will be displayed
            }  
        };
//Now append the TOS string
text.append(getString(R.string.popup));
//Declare that the "TOS" string is a clickableSpan
text.setSpan(clickableSpan, getString(R.string.before).length(), getString(R.string.before).length()+getString(R.string.popup).length(), 0); //Check on API setSpan method
((CheckBox)findViewById(yourview)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); 
((CheckBox)findViewById(yourview)).setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE); //AAAAND WE'RE DONE!
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying this right now. But I can't get the text.append-line to work. I get multiple markers at that line but append is the first. "Syntax error on token "append", Identifier expected after this token" What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry there was an errore in my code. it was R.String with capital S, but S must be in lower case, so R.string.before and R.string.popup

Comment: Aah, should have thought of that. Will try it later and get back! Thanks!

Comment: *doh* I had put the code outside the bracket...so it was on the wrong place! Works perfectly, thank you very much!